# The shortest code to invert bit-wise a binary string

Tags: code-golf, string

Me thinks there aren't enough easy questions on here that beginners can attempt!

The challenge: Given a random input string of 1's and 0's such as:

```
10101110101010010100010001010110101001010
```

Write the shortest code that outputs the bit-wise inverse like so:

```
01010001010101101011101110101001010110101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//v//aEMdBQMdBThpiMRGIzG5WNnIRuEzIRYA) Beats all other answers. Takes I/O as a list of bits.

```
_  # full program
_  # logically negate...
   # (implicit) each element of...
   # implicit input
   # implicit output
```

Comment: Congratulations :)

Answer (score 92):

## J, 5 bytes

Assumes the input string is in variable `b`.

```
b='0'
```

This does not do what it would do in most languages...

> The J comparison operator is just `=` (`=:` and `=.` are global and local assignment, respectively). However, `=` doesn't work like the normal `==` operator: it compares item-by-item. Keep in mind that an array is formed like this: `0 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 4`. `2 = 0 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 4` gives `0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0` for example. This is similar for a string: `'a'='abcadcadda'` doesn't just return `0`, it returns `1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1` (This can be extrapolated to mean `0` with `*/`, which basically means `all`.) In this case however, this behavior is excelent, since we want a string of ones and zeros, or true's and false's. Since J's bools *are* `1` and `0`, this results in an array of `1`'s and `0`'s (They aren't strings, and every other character other than `1` would also result in `0` in this array.) This doesn't need printing: J automatically prints the result of an expression. I hope this was adequate explanation, if not, please ask for something that isn't yet clear in the comments. This answer also could've been `'0'&=` (or `=&'0'`), but I felt that `b='0'` was clearer.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this works? I looked up some docs for J but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Jarett There you go.

Comment: I have tried J. Can't bend my mind to it. Guess I haven't found good docs. Here, have a +1 for being a madman.

Comment: @TheRare I used 'Learning J' from the official J website. I still can't wrap my head around a lot of things, for example control structures and trains...

Comment: And this is why I will never use J.

Comment: @Qix As unreadable as J is, this one actually makes sense to me, and other languages that have operators that take a vector LHS and a scalar RHS do behave similarly.

Comment: What? It doesn't return the right result, does it? The result should have been a text string (without spaces), but with my limited knowledge of J, I think this will return a boolean list with a display form of 0 1 0 1 0 ...

Comment: The answer in J could also just be `-.`.

Comment: This isn't allowed because you can't assume the input is stored in a certain variable. `=&'0'` works for the same number of bytes.

Answer (score 46):

## [GolfScript](http://golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5 bytes

```
{1^}%
```

[Try it online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IjEwMTAxMTEwMTAxMDEwMDEwMTAwMDEwMDAxMDEwMTEwMTAxMDAxMDEwInsxXn0lCg%3D%3D)

#### How it works

- GolfScript reads the entire input from STDIN and places it on the stack as a string.
- `{}%` goes through all characters in the string and executes the code block for all of them.
- `1^` computes the exclusive OR of the characters ASCII code with 1. “0” corresponds to the ASCII code 48, “1” to ASCII code 49.

  Since `48 ^ 1 = 49` and `49 ^ 1 = 48`, this turns 0's into 1's and 1's into 0's.
- Once finished, GolfScript prints the modified string.

Comment: Wait, _golfscript_?

Comment: I had misinterpreted your question. Fixed now.

Comment: I'm always amazed at what can be accomplished in GolfScript. Would you mind explaining the code?

Comment: @tolos: I've edited my answer.

Comment: @ToonAlfrink Golfing languages such as GolfScript are accepted in all challenges, as long as they are 'general-purpose' meaning that they are not designed for specific challenges.

Comment: @kitcar2000 I think he was more surprised that such a language existed, rather than shock of someone daring to use GolfScript in a code golf question ;)

Answer (score 36):

## CJam - 4

```
q1f^
```

This xor's every character with 1.
Unlike the other CJam answer, I'm not assuming the input is already on the stack.

Try it at [http://cjam.aditsu.net/](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q1f%5E&input=10101110101010010100010001010110101001010)

Comment: So *that's* how you use `f`.

Comment: @Dennis Indeed. You can use the sf forum to ask questions btw :)

Answer (score 33):

## x86 machine code on DOS - <del>14</del> <del>13</del> 11 bytes

Well, it did get shorter again! After writing [a solution for an unrelated challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125841/9298), I noticed that the same trick could be applied even here. So here we go:

```
00000000  b4 08 cd 21 35 01 0a 86  c2 eb f7                 |...!5......|
0000000b
```

Commented assembly:

```
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    mov ah,8        ; start with "read character with no echo"
lop:
    ; this loop runs twice per character read; first with ah=8,
    ; so "read character with no echo", then with ah=2, so
    ; "write character"; the switch is performed by the xor below
    int 21h         ; perform syscall
    ; ah is the syscall number; xor with 0x0a changes 8 to 2 and
    ; viceversa (so, switch read <=> write)
    ; al is the read character (when we did read); xor the low
    ; bit to change 0 to 1 and reverse
    xor ax,0x0a01
    mov dl,al       ; put the read (and inverted character) in dl,
                    ; where syscall 2 looks for the character to print
    jmp lop         ; loop
```

---

#### Previous solution - 13 bytes

<del>I think it doesn't get much shorter than this.</del> Actually, it did! Thanks to @ninjalj for shaving off one more byte.

```
00000000  b4 08 cd 21 34 01 92 b4  02 cd 21 eb f3           |...!4.....!..|
0000000d
```

This version features *advanced interactivity™* - after running it from the command line, it spits out the "inverted" characters as long as you write the input digits (which are not echoed); to exit, just do a Ctrl-C.

Unlike the previous solution, this has some trouble running in DosBox - since DosBox [doesn't support Ctrl-C correctly](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?p=139489), you are forced to close the DosBox window if you want to exit. In a VM with DOS 6.0, instead, it runs as intended.

NASM source:

```
org 100h

section .text

start:
    mov ah,8
    int 21h
    xor al,1
    xchg dx,ax
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    jmp start
```

#### Old solution - <del>27</del> <del>25</del> 22 bytes

This accepted its input from the command line; runs smoothly as a .COM file in DosBox.

```
00000000  bb 01 00 b4 02 8a 97 81  00 80 f2 01 cd 21 43 3a  |.............!C:|
00000010  1e 80 00 7c f0 c3                                 |...|..|
```

NASM input:

```
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    mov bx, 1
    mov ah, 2
loop:
    mov dl, byte[bx+81h]
    xor dl, 1
    int 21h
    inc bx
    cmp bl, byte[80h]
    jl loop
exit:
    ret
```

Comment: +1 for code probably not many understand.

Comment: `xchg dx,ax` is 1 byte shorter than `mov dl,al`

Comment: @ninjalj: woa, thank you! It *did* get shorter after all!

Answer (score 26):

## Bash+coreutils, 8 bytes

```
tr 01 10
```

Takes input from STDIN.

---

Or

## sed, 8 bytes

```
y/01/10/
```

Comment: I recently made a golfing library/alias set for Bash https://github.com/professorfish/bash-shelf/. you can shave off one char with that: `y 01 10`

Comment: Where is BASH involved here? What is BASH specific? Every shell can call `tr`...

Comment: @yeti Not every shell calls commands like bash or zsh. In some shells that code alone is a syntax error

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that "shell" means "POSIX-compatible shell" here...

Comment: @professorfish you shave off one char, but then add 48 by including the function. How is that a win?

Comment: @StevenPenny when people use PYG, they don't count the library file towards their score; so in the same way SHELF is a golfing library which counts as a separate language

Comment: @professorfish hey use this library! `y(){ sed 'y/01/10/'; }` Then you can golf it to one char!

Comment: @StevenPenny You just made that library up after the question was posted. SHELF existed before the question was posted.

Comment: @professorfish Does anyone except me actually use PYG?

Comment: @Synthetica I don't know...

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I didn't know you could do that with `tr`--it's going to shave a lot from some of my scripts! I used to translate hex digits `a-f` to caps using six `sed` statements (it was ugly).

Answer (score 21):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/), 4 bytes

```
:~:!
```

Assumes the original string is already on the stack. Prints the modified string.

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) by pasting the following **Code**:

```
"10101110101010010100010001010110101001010":~:!
```

#### How it works

- `:~` evaluates each character of the string, i.e., it replaces the *character* 0 with the *integer* 0.
- `:!` computes the logical NOT of each integer. This turns 0's into 1's and 1's into 0's.

Answer (score 21):

## Brainfuck (<strike>70</strike> 71)

```
>,[>,]<[<]>[<+++++++[>-------<-]<+>>[++<]<[>]++++++++[>++++++<-]>.[-]>]
```

**Explanation:**

```
>,[>,]                       Read characters until there are none left.
<[<]                         Return to start
>[<                          Loop as long as there are characters to invert
  +++++++[>-------<-]        Subtract 49 (ASCII value of 1)
  >[++<]                     If not 0, add 2
  +++[<++++>-]<[>>++++<<-]>> Add 48
  .                          Print
  [-]                        Set current cell to 0
>]                           Loop
```

Comment: ++++++++[<++++++>-] why not this for 48? 8*6 vs. 4*4*3

Comment: @Cruncher Added.

Comment: Why did it get longer? is that because of the "bug fixing"?

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, I had to fix a bug where it would output `a` for `11`.

Answer (score 17):

### PHP - 19 bytes

```php
<?=strtr($s,[1,0]);
```

Yea, not really original, I guess!

Answer (score 12):

## [Pancake Stack](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pancake_Stack), 532 bytes

```
Put this tasty pancake on top!
[]
Put this delicious pancake on top!
[#]
Put this  pancake on top!
How about a hotcake?
If the pancake is tasty, go over to "#".
Eat all of the pancakes!
Put this supercalifragilisticexpialidociouseventhoughtheso pancake on top!
Flip the pancakes on top!
Take from the top pancakes!
Flip the pancakes on top!
Take from the top pancakes!
Put this supercalifragilisticexpialidociouseventhoughthes pancake on top!
Put the top pancakes together!
Show me a pancake!
If the pancake is tasty, go over to "".
```

It assumes the input is terminated by a null character. The strategy is as follows:

- Take a character of input
- Subtract the ascii value of `1` from it.
- Subtract that from `0` (yielding a `1` if we had `0`, or a `0` if we had `1`)
- Add the ascii value of `0` to it
- Print the char.
- Repeat

Answer (score 10):

## C: 29

```
i(char*s){*s^=*s?i(s+1),1:0;}
```

Try it online [here](http://codepad.org/vD4WkoWY).

Thanks for pointing out the XOR trick, Dennis.

Comment: Simpler & shorter: `i(char*s){while(*s)*s++^=1;}`

Comment: Thanks, @edc65! I'm not going to use that, though, since it's an iterative solution rather than a recursive one. I wouldn't want to take credit for it. It's worth noting that replacing your `while` with a `for` still results of a length of 28 characters.

Comment: As you prefer. A recursive solution is not requested, and in my opinion, any time it is possibile, an iterative solution is better than a recursive one. Have fun applying this recursive call to a 10k string.

Comment: Since every call except for the last one is a tail recursive call, I'll bet that a compiler will convert it into a loop in order to re-use the stack frame.

Comment: @millinon Proof!

Comment: Okay, you win. GCC 4.8.3 in Cygwin failed to optimize the tail recursion.

Comment: `i(char*s){*s^=*s&&~i(s+1);}` length 27, assuming i never return -1(i is usually the result *s)

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2.7 – 34*

Oh how much this first one sucks. Pretty ugly, this one is. 63 chars.

```python
print''.join([bin(~0)[3:] if x == '0' else bin(~1)[4:] for x in ''])
```

This one is a bit better but still not that fancy. 44 chars.

```python
print''.join([str(int(not(int(x)))) for x in ''])
```

Since `int(x) and 1` returns `int(x)` if it's not 0 and otherwise False. The solution can be further reduced to 36 chars.

```python
print''.join([str(1-int(x)) for x in ''])
```

Since `join()` takes a generator the brackets can be removed. 32 chars.

```python
print''.join(str(1-int(x))for x in'')
```

And backticks can be used instead of `str()`

```python
print''.join(`1-int(x)`for x in'')
```

*Reduced to 44 from 34 thanks to pointers from @TheRare*

Finding one's complement is difficult in python since `bin(-int)` returns -0bxxx hence the above.

Comment: Ya'know, `(int(x) and 1) == int(x)`

Comment: @TheRare I didn't, thanks for that :)

Comment: As a truth value that is. `int(x) and 1` returns `int(x)` if it's not zero and otherwise False.

Comment: Because of that you can change `int(not(int(x))) -> 1-int(x)`

Comment: Also, you can pass a generator to join (no need for the square brackets) and you don't need spaces around string literals and brackets.

Comment: @TheRare Awesome! I'm gonna document all the steps above in the answer, as reference, cheers!

Comment: Python is my baby, always happy to help. :)

Comment: For the record: zero is false and nonzero is true. For any kind of sequence (list, string...) the same rule applies, but it's checked from the length of the sequence. Thus `'' == False` and `'hi' == True`

Comment: Also, even though it can't be used in this answer, numbers can precede keywords without spaces. `print 4if 1else 2` prints 4.

Comment: Seems like you missed some spaces. Also, backticks can be used to replace repr(). `''.join(\`1-int(x)\`for x in'')`

Comment: Fyi, `repr(x)` for x < maxint is equal to `str(x)`

Comment: That's all I've got regarding this question. You can find more tricks from my other answers (and do check Tips for golfing in Python). :)

Comment: A `print` statement is required, since a REPL cannot be assumed.

Comment: @mbomb007 correct, added.

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 9 characters

```
'y/10/01/'
```

The 9th character is the 'p' flag

Usage:

```
$ echo '10101001' | perl -pe 'y/10/01/'
```

Comment: also works as a sed script `y/10/01/` but one char shorter because it doesn't need any flags

Comment: You don't need single quotes here.

Comment: You can save 1 extra byte, using `;` as the separator: [Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoieTswMTsxMCIsImFyZ3MiOiItcCIsImlucHV0IjoiMTAxMDExMTAxMDEwMTAwMTAxMDAwMTAwMDEwMTAxMTAxMDEwMDEwMTAifQ==)

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript (*ES6*) 36

```javascript
alert(prompt().replace(/./g,x=>x^1))
```

Comment: Assuming input in `s`, `s.replace(/./g,x=>x^1)` are 22 chars.

Comment: I like to actually output and input.

Comment: @nderscore Save 2 chars: `p=prompt(p().replace(/./g,x=>x^1))`

Comment: @GaurangTandon it would have to be `(p=prompt)(p().replace(/./g,x=>x^1))` and that's the same length.

Comment: @nderscore I too thought it to be that way, but it worked without the parenthesis too, strangely.

Comment: @GaurangTandon `p` will be undefined until after `prompt` is called. Afterwards, it will contain a string. It's definitely not valid. You must have had `prompt` stored in `p` before running the code.

Comment: @nderscore I think you are right. I was trying it in FF console so might be that `p` was already defined.

Answer (score 6):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth/), 6 bytes

(Labyrinth is newer than this challenge, so this answer doesn't compete - not that it's winning anyway...)

```
1,
.$@
```

This code assumes that STDIN contains *only* the digits (in particular, no trailing newline).

The instruction pointer (IP) starts in the top left corner going right. While there are digits to read it will cycle in a tight loop through the left-hand 2x2 block: `1` push a 1, `,` read a digit, `$` XOR it with 1 to toggle the last bit, `.` print the result. The IP takes this loop because the top of the stack is positive after the XOR, such that it will take a right-turn. When we hit EOF, `,` returns `-1` instead. Then the XOR will yield `-2` and with this negative value the IP takes a left-turn onto the `@` and the program ends.

This solution should be optimal for Labyrinth: you need `,` and `.` for an I/O loop and `@` to terminate the program. You need at least two characters (here `1` and `$`) to toggle the last bit. And you need at least one newline for a loop which can be terminated.

Unless... if we ignore STDERR, i.e. allow terminating with an error we can save the `@` and we also don't need any way to switch between two paths. We just keep reading and printing until we accidentally try to print a negative value (the `-2`). This allows for at least two 5-byte solutions:

```
1,
.$
```

```
,_1$.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby: 23

```
p $<.read.tr("01","10")
```

Answer (score 5):

## Turing Machine Code, 32 bytes (1 state - 3 colors)

Using the rule table syntax required by [this online TM simulator.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) Borrowed from a post I made to my Googology Wiki user blog a few months back.

```
0 0 1 r *
0 1 0 r *
0 _ _ * halt
```

You may also test this using [this java implementation.](http://pastebin.com/fQz6DBRU)

Answer (score 4):

### R, 27 characters

```
chartr("01","10",scan(,""))
```

Usage:

```
> chartr("01","10",scan(,""))
1: 10101110101010010100010001010110101001010
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "01010001010101101011101110101001010110101"
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts stdin.

```apl
∊⍕¨~⍎¨⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO9AEh0PeqdemhF3aPevkMrHvXOAwn/VwCDAi5DAyA0BJNACCGgGCSBEAUA)

`⍞` prompt stdin

`⍎¨` execute each character

`~` logical NOT

`⍕¨` format each character as text

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP > 5.4  --  37 characters

```
foreach(str_split($s) as $v)echo 1^$v
```

`$s` is the input

[<kbd>**Try it online**</kbd>](http://codepad.org/weOuxj1w)

Comment: Clever abuse of the `<kbd>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.x - 44 bytes

```python
print''.join(`1-int(x)`for x in raw_input())
```

Why make it complex, or use some cheaty variables?

Comment: Its possible to save some extra chars like this: `print''.join('1-int(x)'for x in'input()')`. I couldn't get the backticks in the comment code so substituted them by '.

Comment: @willem For future reference, you can escape them with a backslash: `\`a\\`b\`` -> `a\`b`.

Comment: @willem That doesn't work for input beginning with 0 or input which is bigger than maxint (in base10).

Comment: Thanks @nyuszika7h and didn't think about those cases TheRare so your solution is good

Comment: @willem Real easy to forget about stuff like that. :)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 7 bytes

This is a function that takes a binary string (through `Ans`) as input and returns the output as an inverted (not reversed) string, as specified. For more help, you can read through list application by `not(` on the TI-BASIC wiki. I'm using the compiled version because it is smaller:

```
»*r>Õ¸r
```

In hex:

```
BB 2A 72 3E D5 B8 72
```

**Explanation**

`»*r` - Take function input as string and convert to list

`>`   - Pipe given list to the next operators

`Õ¸r` - Return the inverse of the list

Comment: what are all of the spaces at the end of `»*r>Õ¸r                `?

Comment: @kitcar2000 Oops, I used to have the HEX after that. But after I moved it, I forgot to remove the spaces... I have done it now.

Comment: It should be useful to note that:
1. On the calculator this is displayed as `expr(Ans:Returnnot(Ans`;
2. Because the string is not separated by commas, and it does not start with a `{`, it will evalutate to an integer like 1000010011, not a list;
3. `Return` does not work the way you wrote it;
4. This gives output as a list, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 22 bytes

```
map(\c->"10"!!read[c])
```

I was surprised by the lack of Haskell solutions to this challenge, so here's one. It evaluates to a function that takes a string and returns its inverse.

#### Explanation

Nothing fancy here.

```
map(\c->             )  -- For each character c in the input string:
                  [c]   -- wrap c into a string,
              read      -- convert to integer,
        "10"!!          -- and index the string "10" with it.
```

Answer (score 3):

### Befunge 93, 25 bytes

```
0>~1+:#v_$>:#,_@
 ^   -1<
```

Assuming empty stack and EOF both read -1.

`0` pushes a \0 as a null terminator

`>~1+:#v_` is an input loop, it reads ascii, adds 1, checks for EOF+1=0,

`^   -1<` else subtracts 1 and leaves the pushed ascii value on the stack.

`$>:#,_@` drops the extra copy of zero on top of the stack, then prints the binary string top to bottom

If empty stack reads 0, save 2 bytes with

```
>~:1+#v_$>:#,_@
^   -1<
```

A version around 15 bytes is possible using this same algorithm if EOF = 0, but I don't have such an implementation handy to test with.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 26 chars

```
s=>s.replace(/\d/g,x=>x^1)
```

Comment: Why /\d/g not /./g

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, 24 bytes or 19 bytes

```
,[>++[->++[<]>-]>-.>>>,]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs-KytbLT4rK1s8XT4tXT4tLj4-Pixd&input=MDEwMDEx)

or

```
,[+[<[-->>]<--]<.,]
```

(this one requires an interpreter which will noop on `<` if the data-index is 0)

Both programs use 8-bit wrapping cells. The main part of the programs are the `>++[->++[<]>-]>-` and `+[<[-->>]<--]<` which do some rather convoluted things to flip the last bit of the number.

I'm happy I managed to beat some more 'real' languages like C and Python, not something that happens every day with bf ;)

Comment: If you added an initial > to that first one, so it wouldn't go out of bounds, that'd be a very nice solution. One byte shorter than mine, congrats! Works with EOF->0 or EOF->no change, and doesn't assume anything about cell size, with the specified inputs. Good stuff.

Comment: @DanielCristofani Yeah I thought it was cool that we had two such different looking solutions of such similar size. The reason I didn't add a `>` at the beginning was just because I usually just use tio as my target implementation and it works there.

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 7 bytes

```
'a#@~-,
```

For every character, `c`, in the input, it prints the character with an ascii value of `94 - c`, where 94 is the value of ‘0’ +’1’, or ‘a’

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XT1R2qNPV@f/f0MDAwNDAEEwBAA)

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, 26 bytes

```
,[[-[->++>]>[->>]<<<]>+.,]
```

This flips the last bit of each byte of input. (Assumes EOF -> 0, assumes nothing about cell size, doesn't go out of bounds to the left.)

Answer (score 2):

### Python3, 39

Methinks Python is not the best language for this. :)

```
for i in input():print(1-int(i),end='')
```

If you care about having a newline after the output, here's a 43-character alternative:

```
print(''.join("01"[i<"1"]for i in input()))
```

Comment: Code will work without the `end=''` just a `,` will do :) - unless you care about there being no spaces

Comment: @BritishColour, no, that's Python2. Python3's `print` function requires tweaking the `end` parameter to suppress a newline at the end of each print. Also, according to OP's specification, I think I do care about there being no spaces. :) Thanks for the comment, though!

Comment: Aww, cool, I did't know that! I mainly work in 2.7 :/

Answer (score 2):

### J - 11 chars

Boolean values in J are represented as the integers `0` and `1`, which of course are also valid indices into arrays (in this case, the 2-character array `'01'`)

```
'01'{~'0'&=
```

Comment: I think this answer is technically more correct than the top J answer, which outputs a boolean array instead of a string.

Comment: I actually didn't notice the top-ranked J solution when I posted (don't know how I missed it, but I did). To be fair to that solution, it does explicitly say "this doesn't do what the other solutions do".  BTW, another way to express this (literal output) solution in 11 chars is   [:,":@=&''0'' .

Comment: Hi, thanks for another code! I will be learning more J from you guys. About that statement, I think he was referring to the equal sign, that it compares each item instead of assignment.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 131 bytes

A little late to the party, but here's mine. :)

```
using System;class R{static void Main(string[]a){foreach(var v in a[0].ToCharArray()){Console.Write(int.Parse(v.ToString())^1);}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 13 bytes

```
@(x)[97-x '']
```

After running the above, simply call the function with your input string to get the inverted string. For example running:

```
ans('10101110101010010100010001010110101001010')
```

prints:

```
01010001010101101011101110101001010110101
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BotEngine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BotEngine), 4x8=32

Noncompeting as the language postdates the question.

```
Iv2 0 12
 >e>S SS
    e1e0
   ^< <P
```

With highlighting:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
^1Ṿ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/O8OHOfY@a1vz//1/J0AAIDcEkEEIIKAZJIESVAA)

Explanation:

First of all, if you're familiar with Jelly, you might've noticed that I'm trying to **bitwise-xor with a string**. That sounds all sorts of ridiculous at first, but Jelly actually supports vectorized bitwise-xor'ing with strings, where each char, if it's a digit from 1 to 9, it's treated as such, otherwise it's treated as 0. The only chars in the string will in this case be `'0'` and `'1'`, being treated as themselves, as previously specified. So, bitwise-xor'ing then with `1` will return `0 ^ 1 = 1` for every `'0'` and `1 ^ 1 = 0` for every `'1'` in the string. Right now, our output is a list of `0`s and `1`s, so it's not yet in the correct format. We right now have to find a way to concatenate the integers into a single string, and we don't have a builtin for that. Fortunately, strings in Jelly are lists of 1-char Python strings, so we can simply take the string representation of each of the integers in the list. But wait! That builtin costs us 2 bytes, so let's see if there's a shorter builtin...and there is! Behold the uneval builtin! Unevaling an integer just takes its Jelly string representation, which, for integers, is equivalent to Python's string representation. So why not use it? That's what we'll do, to actually finish our program.

```
^1Ṿ€ Main link, monadic
^1   XOR each char with 1, as specified above
  Ṿ€ Uneval each resulting integer
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-m`, 2 bytes

```
^1
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=XjE=&input=IjEwMTAxMTEwMTAxMDEwMDEwMTAwMDEwMDAxMDEwMTEwMTAxMDAxMDEwIgotbQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 19 keystrokes

```
:s/./-&/g␤qq␁l@qq@q
```

`␤` is <kbd>Return</kbd> and `␁` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

## Explanation

```
:s/./-&/g␤   Negate every digit (01100 -> -0-1-1-0-0)
qq␁l@qq@q   Increment every number (-0-1-1-0-0 -> 10011)
```

Comment: You could also increment every digit, `01100` ==> `12211`, then swap all `2`s for `0`s ==> `10011`. Save 1 byte doing `:s/2/0/g` instead of negation

Comment: @roblogic As far as i know there isn't a way to increment single digits in vim. I would have to insert separators in between each character which would waste more bytes than it saves

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <strike>38</strike> 36 bytes

```forth
: f 0 do dup c@ 1 xor emit 1+ loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLDoJADEX3fsXJbI2m41Ki8UPcEGZ4JEInUBL8ehwMnC6ak3vbWkdrL029rXW9UyMEJcyJ6oVn0ZHYd4Y/81FNFLmUs5Hb1rFvilwdPJ64fFzwpgxhYtI@MnRVJL/uS7NuaDDF2ojOlmY7TQ4vIj4jjvT3g93l4Mhln@zrDw)

-2 bytes thanks to  @bubbler

#### Explanation

Gets the string character by character. For each character:

1. checks if it's equal to 49 and then adds -1 to the result (forth uses -1 as true).
2. Prints the space right-aligned in a space of size 1 (removes space after number that `.` normally outputs)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                \ start a new word definition
  0 do             \ start counted loop from 1 to string-length
    dup c@         \ duplicate the string address and get the ascii value of the char at the beginning
    49 = 1+        \ check if equal to 49 and add 1 to the result (forth uses -1 as true)
    1 .r           \ output right-aligned in a space of size (removes trailing space)
    1+             \ increment the string address
  loop             \ end the loop
;                  \ end the word definition
```

Comment: Using `1 xor emit` (charcode output instead of number output) gives [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYzLDoJADEX3fsXJbI2m41Ki8UPcEGZ4JEInUBL8ehwMnC6ak3vbWkdrL029rXW9UyMEJcyJ6oVn0ZHYd4Y/81FNFLmUs5Hb1rFvilwdPJ64fFzwpgxhYtI@MnRVJL/uS7NuaDDF2ojOlmY7TQ4vIj4jjvT3g93l4Mhln@zrDw).

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 34 bytes

```
(load library
(d F(q((A)(map not A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jJz8xRSEnM6kosaiSSyNFwU2jUEPDUVMjN7FAIS@/RMHxv4abgkahgoahgoECBBsqINgQjMxCpWE6sKjV1NT8DwA)

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 37 bytes

```
(d F(q((A)(i A(c(i(h A)0 1)(F(t A)))(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxCoBAEAO/knK2855wzX1ECxdEFK/x9euhiAoWIUNIUn3eJ9@WCAYVVsiGK9PjjMrWKRmF2tCMoIhVJLX8VNLDl9709Xvx023ncQA)

surprisingly close to the library version.

Comment: -1 byte in the non-library version: `(i(h A)0 1)` -> `(s 1(h A))`

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 89

```cobra
class P
    def main
        r=''
        for i in Console.readLine,r+=if(i==c'1','0','1')
        print r
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# in LINQPad, <strike>64</strike> 63

```
foreach(var c in Console.ReadLine())Console.Write((char)(c^1));
```

**EDIT**: removed one character by using XOR 1

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl - 23 bytes

```
string map {0 1 1 0} $s
```

Not quite the shortest but highly readable.

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript (28 bytes)

```js
for(i of prompt(r=''))r+=1-i
```

Just subtraction.

### Alternative 1 (28 bytes)

```js
for(i of prompt(r=''))r+=i^1
```

A simple bitwise not.

### Alternative 2 (29 bytes)

```js
for(i of prompt(r=''))r+=2+~i
```

`~'1'` is `-2` and `~'0'` is `-1`, so `2+~i` gives `0` for `1` and `1` for `0`.

### Alternative 3 (29 bytes)

```js
for(i of prompt(r=''))r+=+!+i
```

The last `+` changes `i` to a number, `!` converts it to a boolean (`0` is `false` and anything else is `true`) and inverts it, and the first `+` converts it to a number (`false` becomes `0` and `true` becomes `1`).

Answer (score 1):

Linux amd64 assembly version, 370 bytes, generates small ELF executable (392 bytes after strip --strip-all).

```
global _start

_start:
        mov rsi, [rsp+16] ; argv[1]
        xor rdx, rdx
loop:
        mov bl, [rsi+rdx]
        test bl, bl
        jz print
        xor bl, 1
        mov [rsi+rdx], bl
        inc rdx
        jmp loop
print:  
        mov rdi, 1 ; stdout
        mov rax, 1 ; write
        syscall
        mov rax, 60 ; exit
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java - <s>120</s> <s>103</s> 94

This is for hdante :)

```
class I{public static void main(String[]a){for(int
x:a[0].getBytes())System.out.print(49-x);}}
```

It takes the string as a command-line argument.

Comment: a streaming Java 8 solution (takes lines of 0 and 1): `class D{public static void main(String[] b){new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines().forEach((String i)->System.out.print(i.equals("0")?'1':'0'));}}`

Comment: a solution that takes the word "random" in the question literally and makes it's own input: `class C{public static void main(String[] b){new java.util.Random().ints(0,2).forEach((int i)->System.out.print(i==0?'1':'0'));}}`

Comment: reads ACSII from stdin (143 bytes): `class B{public static void main(String[] b)throws java.io.IOException{int c;while((c=System.in.read())!=-1)System.out.print(c=='0'?'1':'0');}}`

Comment: reads everything from stdin with the Scanner trick (165 bytes): `class A{public static void main(String[] b){for(char a:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\A").next().toCharArray())System.out.print(a=='0'?'1':'0');}}`

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Um, thanks, but why don't you post a separate answer? Also, your solutions are longer.

Comment: The question has been protected. I also think it makes sense to group answers by language. You are correct, they are longer, when expressed in this syntax.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Protected means you need to have at least 10 reputation to answer, and you have 101. I don't think grouping answers as comments really makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, to tell the truth, it's not as verbose as I expected it to be.

Comment: @aditsu one needs to get 10 points (= at least one answer or 2 question upvotes) *on this site* – the 100 rep from the association bonus doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

### ><> (6 bytes)

Assuming you don't mind the code exiting with an error, the following works:

```
{2%0=n
```

Example run:

```
$ python3 fish.py binary.fish -s "100010101101111001"
011101010010000110
something smells fishy...
```

This errors when it runs out of values left on the stack.
If it has to actually end correctly, 11 bytes works;

```
{2%0=nl0=?;
```

Example:

```
$ python3 fish.py binary.fish -s "10111111101101001"
01000000010010110
```

Essentially, each piece of code is doing the same thing: `{` shifts the entire stack to the left, moving the first value entered in the command call to the top of the stack; `2%` takes the modulus of the top value with 2 (so `"1" -> 49 (ASCII code) -> 1` and `"0" -> 48 -> 0`); `0=` pushes 0 to the stack and pops the top two values off, pushing 1 to the stack if they are equal and 0 otherwise; and `n` prints the numerical value of the value on top of the stack.
The additional bit in the second piece just checks if there are any values left on the stack and ends if there aren't.

Comment: I don't believe this warrants an additional answer since it's so similar, but here's an alternate program to your error-less one: `i:0(?;2%0=n`. This one doesn't need a flag to populate the stack, so I guess it's technically 3 bytes shorter (or 2 depending on how you want to treat spaces).

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>33</s> 29 Bytes

```
$args-split0-replace1,0-join1
```

Similar, but distinct, from DarkAjax's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31425/42963).

Uses inline operators to split on `0`'s (which results in a collection of strings of `1`'s), replace those `1`'s with `0`'s, and then join the collection back together with `1`'s (i.e., replacing the `0`'s that were removed when we split with `1`'s).

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 60 bytes

Not the shortest solution but i wanted to see if it could be achieved without a loop.

Exclusive or on a binary of ones same length as the input string (equivalent of 2**n - 1 where n is length of input). Padding with zfill was not ideal...

```
a=input()
print(bin(int(a,2)^2**len(a)-1)[2:].zfill(len(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Chicken Scheme - 85

Me thinks this problem needs *more parenthesis*!

`(display(list->string(map(lambda(s)(if(eqv? s#\0)#\1 \0))(string->list(read-line)))))`

Switching `display` for `write` saves 2 more characters, at the cost of quotes around the answer.

> Fun fact:
>
> A little over 20% of those 85 characters above are parentheses. Achievement unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

### ><>, <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
i1+:?!;2%n
```

Explanation:

```
i1+:?!;2%n

i          Input as code point
 1+        Add one
   :       Duplicate the top item
    ?!;    Terminate if EOF
       2%  Modulo the top item of the stack by two.
           Because we added one earlier, this is effectively flipping the output.
         n Output as integer
```

[Try it here](http://fishlanguage.com/playground)

Comment: 10 bytes: `i1+:?!;2%n`. I don't know ><>, but is ? supposed to pop off the stack?

Comment: Dang. That's clever. Will do :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Simplex v.0.7](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Simplex/), <s>3</s> 4 bytes

Noncompeting; languages postdates question.

```
bTng
b    ~~ take string input
 Tn  ~~ applies negation function on each character
   g ~~ clear strip and output it
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Oh, a _negation_. I reade reverse as in, _reverse_. Editting now

Comment: Yeah a lot of people get that mixed up on this question... anyway cool lang, I hope you get an online interpreter set up soon so I can continue to feed my need to learn esolangs while also being lazy :^)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman XD Thanks! You bumped up the interpreter a few spaces on my priority list. (I have quite a lot going on ATM, so I'd expect the interpreter to go online sometime this weekend.)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>57</s> <s>53</s> <s>52</s> <s>46</s> 41 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join(['10'[c>'0']for c in s])
```

Here's another one, with a different approach:

```
def b(s):return''.join([str(int(not(int(c))))for c in s])
```

Shortened with lambda anonymity per the advice of [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego).
Shortened with '10' instead of tuple of characters per advice of [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)

(Thanks!)

Comment: You can turn this into an unnamed lambda to make it shorter: `lambda s:''.join([('1','0')[c>'0']for c in s])`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Here's another 5-byte savings: `('1','0')` -> `'10'`.

Comment: Dang! I should've thought of that one!

Comment: You can pass a generator object to `''.join`, so you don't need square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 66 bytes

```
function a(b)return b:gsub("1","2"):gsub("0","1"):gsub("2","0")end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque, 9 bytes

```
)-.'/'1r~
```

[Try online here](http://104.167.104.168/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=%221100101000%22%29-.%27%2F%271r~).

Explanation:

```
)-. -- decrement every character (1 -> 0, 0 -> /)
'/'1r~ -- replace / with 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, <s>73</s>, <s>71</s>, 67 bytes

```
q(X):-X='0',write(1);write(0).
p(X):-atom_chars(X,L),maplist(q,L).
```

Not an optimal language for this challenge.
Having input in string-form makes for an expensive conversion to list.
Could probably be improved on though.

**Testing:**
Try it out [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 85 bytes

`void i(String s) {s.chars().mapToObj(c->(char)49-(int)c).forEach(System.out::print);}`

I like Java. I like streams. Gotta do both.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Why is this noncompeting?

Comment: Want to be calm just now.

Comment: Golfed: void j(String s){s.chars().map(c->49-c).forEach(System.out::print);} (-17)
Good job otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>48</s> 41 bytes

```
foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c)echo+!$c;
```

Saved 7 bytes thanks to Jörg Hülsermann!

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dea6552d4ecfa6e40583ec8ff3ca89253e5749ca)

Comment: wrong inversion :^(

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon thanks, It sounded a bit obvious to me but because I didn't get the proper meaning of the question... I'm going to fix the answer.

Comment: '+!$c` instead of `($c>0?0:1)` for the output and delete the space in the loop

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Great thanks! I tried to use `!$c`but only `1` printed in the output, no `0`, I didn't know about the `+` thing. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 71 bytes

```
(λ(s)(list->string(map(λ(x)(if(eq? x #\0)#\1 #\0))(string->list s))))
```

Detailed version:

```
(define f
  (λ(s)
    (list->string
     (map
      (λ(x)
        (if(eq? x #\0)
           #\1
           #\0))
      (string->list s)))))

(f "1010111")
```

Output:

```
"0101000"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clora](https://github.com/opsxcq/cloralang), 6 bytes (Noncompeting)

```
<0I?01
```

Explanation:

`<0I` Means, `if 0 < I` (Current input character), set flag as true

`?01` If the flag is true (I is 1), output 0, else output 1

Comment: Looks like 6 bytes to me...

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, <s>74</s> 44 Bytes

VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and inverts the binary sting by replacement

```vba
?Replace(Replace(Replace([A1],1,2),0,1),2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC 3, 40 bytes

**Down 10 bytes thanks to suggestions from 12Me21.**

While I like [12Me21's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109133/42096), it doesn't actually answer the question.

```
INPUT S$WHILE""<S$?!VAL(SHIFT(S$));
WEND
```

This doesn't print a linebreak afterwards though, so if you did this on the console you might get something like `001010101OK`. Oh well, nothing about it in the question.

```
INPUT S$             'get string
WHILE ""<S$          'while input string isn't empty:
  ? !VAL(SHIFT(S$)); '-SHIFT a character off our string
                     '-find the opposite value with VAL and !
                     '-print that value, omitting newline
WEND                 'while end
```

Comment: There's a way to do this without using `VAL(`

Comment: You could use an infinite loop and let the program end with an error: `INPUT S$@L?!VAL(SHIFT(S$));:GOTO@L` for 34 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Noether, 18 bytes

<sub>***100th Answer! :D***</sub>

```
I~sL(1si/W-Pi1+~i)
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=SX5zTCgxc2kvVy1QaTErfmkp&input=IjEwMDAxMDEwIg)

Loops through each character in the string, inverting each character.

**Explanation:**

```
I  - Push input to stack
~s - Store the top of the stack in the variable s
L  - Pop string off the top and push its length
(  - Pop off the stack and repeat code between brackets until stack equals popped value
1  - Push the number 1
s  - Push the value of variable s
i  - Push the value of variable i (all variables are initialised to zero)
/  - Pop a string and number, n, off stack and push the character at index n
W  - Convert string to number
-  - Pop two numbers off stack and push the numbers subtracted
P  - Print top of stack
i  - Push value of variable i
1  - Push number 1
+  - Pop top two numbers and push the addition
~i - Pop top off stack and store in variable i
)  - End loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

`jkms!s`

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jkms%21s&input=%27101110100101101%27)

Takes input as a string. New at this so it probably isn't optimal but the shortest pyth one here so far!

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 12 bytes

```
i?./^\'1c$@O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z/TXk8/LkbdMFnFwf//f0MDBAQBQ0NDAA)

cube form:

```
    i ?
    . /
^ \ ' 1 c $ @ O
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Answer (score 1):

## Sinclair ZX81, Timex TS1000/1500, ~60 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 PRINT A$
 3 FOR I=1 TO LEN A$
 4 PRINT NOT VAL A$(I);
 5 NEXT I
```

This technique iterates over each byte of the string, taking it's numeric value and printing the `NOT` equivalent. In ZX81 terms, `NOT 1` is `0` and `NOT 0` is `1`. `RUN` the program and enter your binary string, followed by `NEW LINE` (or the Enter key).

Simple test case shown below.

[image: ZX81 flip the bits]

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 51 bytes

Performs 3 substitutions: 0 -> 5, 1 -> 0, 5 -> 1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,5),1,0),5,1)
```

For fun, replacing the third substitution (5 -> 1) eith a `/5` works for input where first character is `0`.  But for others, need to pad with for length.  Resulting in 59 bytes:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,5),1,0)/5,REPT(0,LEN(A1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Pure Bash shell solution. 87 bytes.**

```
while((n<=${#1}));do
case "${1:$n:1}" in
0)printf 1;;1)printf 0;;
esac;n=$((n+1));done
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first solution!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 11 bytes

```perl6
{TR/10/01/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzokSN/QQN/AUL/2v0o8UMTGQMHQTq8oPydHw9JSUy8rPzPPmkuvOLESSKqlgRn/AQ)

Simple transliterate that turns all `1`s to `0`s and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
€_J
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaeK///w0NgNAQTAIhhIBikARCFAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
€      # Map over the digits of the (implicit) input
 _     #  Negative boolean: 0 becomes 1, everything else (so the 1s) becomes 0
  J    # After the map, join everything together (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 79 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T T   S S S T N
_Push_49][S N
S _Duplicate_49][S N
S _Duplicate_49][T  N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][T    S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_1][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_0][N
N
N
_Exit][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_0][S S S T    N
_Push_1][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_1][T  N
S T _Print_integer_to_STDOUT][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace can only take input as integer or character, we must add a trailing character (other than `0` or `1`; like a newline, space, a letter, etc.) to indicate we're done with the input-string after reading it character by character.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##RYtdCoAwDIOfk1P0CNuRRAbuTVDw@DXpBPvz0aTtc8x7XOe2j0xGqAIwGCVByLAFKYl14qFWdNS5YRKsb2b2puxF5cLXXvwuXw) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Example run: [`input = 100`](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/n0tBAYgUODlBBJcCmMvJxQkUAAlxAnlADkQJiAGW4gIBsHIQASK5OLnAurn@/zc0MOACAA)**

```
Command       Explanation                     Stack        Heap      STDIN   STDOUT

NSSN          Create Label_LOOP               []
 SSSTTSSSTN   Push 49                         [49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49,49]
 TNTS         Read STDIN as character         [49,49]      {49:49}   1
 TTT          Retrieve                        [49,49]      {49:49}
 TSST         Subtract (49-49)                [0]          {49:49}
 SNS          Duplicate 0                     [0,0]        {49:49}
 NTSSN        If 0: Jump to Label_1           [0]          {49:49}
 NSSSN        Create Label_1                  [0]          {49:49}
  TNST        Print to STDOUT as integer      []           {49:49}           0
  NSNN        Jump to Label_LOOP              []           {49:49}

 SSSTTSSSTN   Push 49                         [49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49,49]
 TNTS         Read STDIN as character         [49,49]      {49:48}   0
 TTT          Retrieve                        [49,48]      {49:48}
 TSST         Subtract (49-49)                [1]          {49:48}
 SNS          Duplicate 0                     [1,1]        {49:48}
 NTSSN        If 0: Jump to Label_1           [1]          {49:48}
 SSSTN        Push 1                          [1,1]        {49:48}
 TSST         Subtract (1-1)                  [0]          {49:48}
 NTSTN        If 0: Jump to Label_0           []           {49:48}

 NSSTN        Create Label_0                  []           {49:48}
  SSSTN       Push 1                          [1]          {49:48}
  NSSSN       Create Label_1                  [1]          {49:48}
  TNST        Print to STDOUT as integer      []           {49:48}           1
  NSNN        Jump to Label_LOOP              []           {49:48}

 SSSTTSSSTN   Push 49                         [49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49,49]
 TNTS         Read STDIN as character         [49,49]      {49:48}   0
 TTT          Retrieve                        [49,48]      {49:48}
 TSST         Subtract (49-49)                [1]          {49:48}
 SNS          Duplicate 0                     [1,1]        {49:48}
 NTSSN        If 0: Jump to Label_1           [1]          {49:48}
 SSSTN        Push 1                          [1,1]        {49:48}
 TSST         Subtract (1-1)                  [0]          {49:48}
 NTSTN        If 0: Jump to Label_0           []           {49:48}

 NSSTN        Create Label_0                  []           {49:48}
  SSSTN       Push 1                          [1]          {49:48}
  NSSSN       Create Label_1                  [1]          {49:48}
  TNST        Print to STDOUT as integer      []           {49:48}           1
  NSNN        Jump to Label_LOOP              []           {49:48}

 SSSTTSSSTN   Push 49                         [49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49]
 SNS          Duplicate 49                    [49,49,49]
 TNTS         Read STDIN as character         [49,49]      {49:10}   \n
 TTT          Retrieve                        [49,10]      {49:10}
 TSST         Subtract (49-10)                [39]         {49:10}
 SNS          Duplicate 39                    [39,39]      {49:10}
 NTSSN        If 0: Jump to Label_1           [39]         {49:10}
 SSSTN        Push 1                          [39,1]       {49:10}
 TSST         Subtract (39-1)                 [38]         {49:10}
 NTSTN        If 0: Jump to Label_0           []           {49:10}
 NNN          Exit program                    []           {49:10}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 34 bytes

Fully portable (not just one or two character encodings).

```
f(char*s){for(;*s;)*s++^='0'^'1';}
```

Output is in-place modification of the string.

A less portable version would use a simple number in place of the expression `'0'^'1'` - e.g. `1` for ASCII or EBCDIC - saving up to 6 bytes.

## Demo

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "10101110101010010100010001010110101001010";
    f(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: Did you at all read the answer? I did say that you could use `1` for ASCII or EBCDIC systems, but that's not fully portable.

Answer (score 1):

## [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), 15 bytes

```
iSBql[n1~-o]~*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otyUwuzUks@v8/M9ipMCc6z7BONz@2Tsv6/39DAwyIDAxQAUgEAQE)

### Explanation

```
i               # Read input as string.
 S              # Push array of characters in the string.
  B             # Push every character in the array to the stack.
   q            # Reverse the stack.
    l           # Push the size of the stack.
     [     ]    # Push a function that does the following:
      n         # Convert top of stack to int.
       1~-      # Push 1, swap the top two items in the stack and subtract them.
                  This takes a character x in the input string to 1-x, resulting in the bit negation.
          o     # Output the top item of the stack     
            ~   # Swap the top two items in the stack.
             *  # Call the above function the same number of times as length of the input string.
                  (That is, for each bit in the input string, negate the bit and output it.)
              ; # Exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

Shell builtins only: specifically, the [XOR operator **`^`**](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html).

[29 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@cWKJgp5CmYGOjoO7q76bOpayoX1pcpJ@UmadfBZS3sbFRiTZUUzaMM4xVqTa00k5QMVAAMQxrE2r/A3VwJWfk5qcoaFcopHHp6acpGBoAoSGYBEIIAcL/AQ): `` <<<$[1&#1^1]${1:+`$0 ${1:1}`} ``     <sub>*recursion, by @GammaFunction*</sub>

<s>[30 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIUJBQ6Vao9jKStOwVrOgKDOvJE1BJdowLiL2////hgZAaAgmgRBCQDFIAiEKAA)</s>: `for X (${(s::)1})printf $[1^X]`   <sub>*more efficient `for`, by @GammaFunction*</sub>

<s>[32 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIUIhM09BpVqj2MpK07DWuqAoM68kTUEl2jAuIvb///@GBkBoCCaBEEJAMUgCIQoA)</s>: `for X in ${(s::)1};printf $[1^X]`

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 35 bytes

[35 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQpmBjo6Du6u@m/j81OSNfQSXaME6l2tDKwMqwNhbE0E5QMVAAMQxrE2r/AxVyJWfk5qcoaFcopHHp6acpGBoAoSGYBEIIAcUgCYTofwA): `` echo $[1^${1:0:1}]${1:+`$0 ${1:1}`} ``   <sub>*recursion, by @GammaFunction*</sub>

<s>[44 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEPDOtNGpVrZsNY6U1tbU9O6WqGgKDOvJE1BJdowTqXa0CrTyrA21rr2////hgZAaAgmgRBCQDFIAiEKAA)</s>: `for((;i<${#1};i++));{ printf $[1^${1:i:1}];}`

Comment: [35 for Bash using `${:+recursion}`.](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQpmBjo6Du6u@m/j81OSNfQSXaME6l2tDKwMqwNhbE0E5QMVAAMQxrE2r/AxVyJWfk5qcoaFcopHHp6acpGBoAoSGYBEIIAcUgCYTofwA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: [`for X (...)` form for 30 in Zsh](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIUJBQ6Vao9jKStOwVrOgKDOvJE1BJdowLiL2////hgZAaAgmgRBCQDFIAiEKAA)

Comment: [29 in Zsh using recursion](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@cWKJgp5CmYGOjoO7q76bOpayoX1pcpJ@UmadfBZS3sbFRiTZUUzaMM4xVqTa00k5QMVAAMQxrE2r/A3VwJWfk5qcoaFcopHHp6acpGBoAoSGYBEIIAcL/AQ). Note, too many `fork` calls get denied on TIO.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant & creative feedback!

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 62 bytes

```
2a2x1v4a8m2x0v1x0f1a1o1f0x1x1f1r3x1v2e3x0v0e1s1o1f0x1x2f0a0x1f
```

Works for any input file of 1's and 0's terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v                   # Set variable 1 equal to 2
4a8m2x0v                 # Set variable 0 equal to 48
1x0f1a1o1f               # Function 0
                         # Add 1 to the register, output, then jump to function 1
1x1f1r3x1v2e3x0v0e1s1o1f # Function 1
                         # Read a byte of input
                         # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
                         # Jump to function 0 if it equals variable 0
                         # Otherwise, subtract 1 from the register, output,
                         # then jump back to the start of function 1
1x2f0a                   # Function 2
                         # Add 0 to the register
1f                       # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
†
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigKAiLCIiLCJbMCwxLDAsMSwxLDAsMSwxLDAsMSwxLDAsMSwwLDEsMSwxLDAsMCwwLDEsMSwwXSJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Seed](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), 4001 bytes

```
12 22467800860124070178830737520017462583858242261688818083563967964459492073122807697499205500520814270057390910850070898023779372337845606451434999597324513116009103282793138363889251070541548956324245082329674394635061703600124082725719347051922338244963555154324370355238030226191755446700141538448744882828401289257105544925638425778005923480537339123570198316859318125063896435356052960878798108984454300034802385262580209301524236136248719519921946031828718409466542238635588879942564163080889109125277745199171883349061520869997942949639546109688688788190940395919772174262841234098191606390237829497693620421210677789981161937899626045826080802574655497452130041254940986107805698757014260882449573944556602129769737703315763962652354056343895230431267996034382053925203053307001003333804173344801825634791820695141553355621023990400711189803634409496082889140704419749000824286397618093636247662749951187708752873519950104578968340972361618524412325645098713699731021088671725575084245344751522649567245480821120339220564646068943031946783303903697367253955714044444736783957222575572241319818457276409266126595415669073513253183989135440889608714964831521757016620819816850763183162405901035026179418588534822021105457990128662024405359920540011554379532044740831623941815066395865241509740805855343347903491296220782048364612164349265833607844707347159345067371895976293721572188715573401930387350648051542907586789168439477137453524755084958277596405623536912666957589117645881846750438246766165234099806368247856450957646185589082789378547512134409783416060602945874310445999221638049305359530033182401798760305340764937308446248612494477798147335809113299917339976366532774445821809050635734106638274070832257786599315353165493685027605339636316348551394743274112960759253605959515456316478044100123168731682979291374569338572092082869123150387567271191092971638844368321984656886356084605909222030710150000407927489274727063860328145859688080273381880596439423213732909155412724144303878876832255238035073247552082203299616735975900731438704855017567941085339636443620043767639365385673296669965015825191217275207514003602363380064736873151800792178445714348743862550536432711191527537777366511426388278812825671029910854980928682139046501881451902927544724305377340163929216935010743857978836424566071713806944632017276688837315532946743339777915616030011161708954637903288482182308670771005462983742584744344066707662057998285468364681750429465060696832417939697844369858677491150502866685111618816518160802785248209223095658989030839275159107736257541077894710268795690490482316124636074318996932638195319298458661969220607094970584356214121664089841491446209143755531268896976923041463145479413553581327439998726678121104922190297288358873060196647710463668580909699483989882954140817314685815779877890795712718361623431063616953603383264989936053474641614569529053703569694229770237259956181704387417633362063048253194547238628479951576197180647512354097114011449776247632199450163435658817379247320758050414702476804424429759571774687799269847272241040125929986561154071306898735707411802043172870573801610582124052361577796587449450980584367871604033018651000439099472710719881306790290886915898325194141014611846079395667807264562687901178526268969175193051163108905837484413417816154510711926841899863006227166207619380521870269028440296101561963248505036429083164400024679203296550171382565396820939898890114978768872643479708314697168816959694732131149657059289619022081777426733646802338248337315031956161258755974424581432365955447254124547801478393685789570178512768654602326030764253268669713151354485782078002288517388185165706102804594623909510752146365156058948091625484531645749465785838573681651816640209540090471551546428418684230905961729447735111300809970327136013512273479286642147001855525584783017763430816620169651297763121245380125111624755448069360703085235290573427681024676161302183767200167011805149778397302405685676191974385732998259279459936937214011
```

Doesn't work on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 29 bytes

```
x->replace(x,'0'=>'1','1'=>0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBkjQFW4WlpSVpuhZ7K3TtilILchKTUzUqdNQN1G3t1A3VdYDY1s5AE6LmpolDcUZ-uUKahpKhARAagkkghBBQDJJAiCpB9S5YAKEB)

Julia also has [the operator `~` for bitwise not](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#Bitwise-Operators):

````
julia> x=0b10101110101010010100010001010110101001010
0x0000015d5288ad4a

julia> bitstring(x)
"0000000000000000000000010101110101010010100010001010110101001010"

julia> bitstring(~x)
"1111111111111111111111101010001010101101011101110101001010110101"
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 20 bytes

```
x->join('1'.-[x...])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBkjQFW4WlpSVpuhZbKnTtsvIz8zTUDdX1dKMr9PT0YjUhUjdNHIoz8ssV0jSUDA2A0BBMAiGEgGKQBEJUCap3wQIIDQA)

-4 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/Steffan)

Comment: 22 bytes: `x->@. "01"['2'-[x...]]`

Comment: Actually this works for 20: `x->join('1'.-[x...])`

Answer (score 1):

## [BitBitJump](https://github.com/TryItOnline/bitbitjump) `-16`, 61 bytes

```
-1 96
-1 87
22 -1
87 -1
-1 -1
-1 -1
-1 -1
-1 -1
-1 -1
-1 -1 0
```

TIO doesn't allow passing arguments to the compiler so I called the program manually.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7LCsIwEEX38xUXXPeRLtoKxV0FV924l6QGm9omIU0Xfn1MBRFEkBkOzJ07D8GXIexwPnUQUukbLHde8Wl6QDhzlxpWOvhBQhs3E/Xc49Cbq0yFGNE0uLTdMSQM@5Ii64qKAgmjutoYlX9EHrYV1FtkxvpMKB9zXGebTUq8rqRE360o82WO4yXez/zyuFV/PLEILI/BcnoC)

16-bit mode is not very useful outside of minimizing offsets because self-modifying code is unable to encode a negative offset. This is because in all word sizes, the offsets are read stored in an int32 array and they are not properly sign extended unless the source was sign extended.

So for example, if I do

```
    .include lib.bbj

    .copy A, B
    A:0 B:-1
```

The result will be this:

```
    A:65535 B:-1
```

The code expects a string followed by a newline.

Explained:

```
    # Read bit 0 from stdin to "x"
  L:-1   i:x
    # Store bit 1 to bit 7 of the jump offset of this instruction.
    # When '\n' (00001010), bit 1 will be set and instead of jumping to the next
    # instruction (96), it will jump to e (224)
    -1     j'7     j:?
    # Bits [7:6] of i are 01. When the first bit of stdin is copied here,
    # it will either target i'6 or i'7.
    # It basically becomes {1, 0}[i], flipping the bit.
  x:i'6    -1
    # When the IP interprets e, it sees -1, 240, -1, which exits.
    #   -1 240 -1
    j'7  e:-1
    # Copy the rest of stdin to stdout
    -1     -1
    -1     -1
    -1     -1
    -1     -1
    -1     -1
    # Loop
    -1     -1    L
```

This code compiles to this.

```
-1 96 48    # 1111111111111111 0000000001100000 0000000000110000
-1 87 96    # 1111111111111111 0000000001010111 0000000001100000
22 -1 144   # 0000000000010110 1111111111111111 0000000010010000
87 -1 192   # 0000000001010111 1111111111111111 0000000011000000
-1 -1 240   # 1111111111111111 1111111111111111 0000000011110000
-1 -1 288   # 1111111111111111 1111111111111111 0000000100100000
-1 -1 336   # 1111111111111111 1111111111111111 0000000101010000
-1 -1 384   # 1111111111111111 1111111111111111 0000000110000000
-1 -1 432   # 1111111111111111 1111111111111111 0000000110110000
-1 -1 0     # 1111111111111111 1111111111111111 0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
1Æ^
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpNS7IKlpSVpuhZLDA-3xS0pTkouhgosuKmtZGgAhIZgEgghBBSDJBCiShA9AA)

Inspired by Dennis's GolfScript answer.

##### Explanation

The `B` flag does most of the heavy-lifting here.

```python
    # Implicit input. The B flag converts the
    # input string to a list of codepoints.
1Æ^ # Compute the bitwise XOR of each codepoint
    # with 1, so 48 -> 49 and 49 -> 48
    # Implicit output. The B flag converts the
    # integer list to a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>37</s>  32

```
$*[0].each_char{|x|p x==?0?1:0}
```

Comment: 32: `$*[0].each_char{|x|p x==?0?1:0}`

Answer (score 0):

### Scala, 33 bytes

```
print(readLine map(c=>"10"(c&1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell 41

```
(($args-split''-ne'')|%{1-bxor$_})-join''
```

**Explanation**:

It reads the input and splits it to turn it into an array. Then it iterates through every element of the array and uses the bitwise exclusive or to turn 1 to 0 and 0 to 1, and then joins the result and prints it to console...

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 56

```js
a=prompt()
for(b='',r=/./g;c=r.exec(a);b+=c^1);
alert(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch - 167 Bytes

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&set l=-1&set s=%~1&set o=%~1
:c
if defined s set/al+=1&set s=%s:~1%&goto c
for /l %%a in (%l%,-1,0)do set/p=!o:~%%a,1!<nul
```

Could be cut down a bit by using Powershell to get the length of the input - then again, it could be cut down a lot by using a different language.

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - <strike>31</strike> 28 chars

edit thanks to [cfrick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24901/cfrick)'s insightful comment:

```
print args[0].tr("01","10")
```

previous:

```
args[0].each{print it=="1"?0:1}
```

Comment: groovy also has `tr`.  e.g. ``b.tr('01','10')``

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3 - 50 bytes

```
r=str.replace
r(r(r(input(),'1','a'),'0','1'),'a','0')
```

It's not as short as some of the other ones, but it takes a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

## php, 41 bytes

Where $s is the string:

```
str_replace(array(1,0,2),array(2,1,0),$s)
```

This works because the str_replace() function is just a loop when given an array. This works like this:

- replace all `1` with `2`
- then all `0` with `1`
- then the `2` back to `0`

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 101 bytes

```
class R{String r(String s){return s.replaceAll("0", "2").replaceAll("1", "0").replaceAll("2", "1");}}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
class R{
    String r(String s){
        return s.replaceAll("0", "2").replaceAll("1", "0").replaceAll("2", "1");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the task ... it was not to reverse the order, but to swap 1 and 0.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, corrected it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Vitsy, <s>13</s> 12 Bytes

Byte size reduced by newest version ending execution on end of file*.

```
I\[i1+2M]l\N
I\             Repeat everything in the [] for input stack's length.
  [i1+2M]      Grab an item from the input, add 1 and modulo 2 (to invert the number).
         l\    Repeat the next character for the currently active program stack's length.
           N   Output the top item of the stack as a number.
```

*In situations that don't involve special cases.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica / Wolfram Language

Three solutions here, all of which assume that the argument is being passed as a string in a variable "b". If it is being passed in another format (as I think some of the other solutions here assume), shorter solutions are possible.

**Method 1, using bitwise operator for 64 char**

```
StringJoin[ToString[BitNot[#] + 2] & /@ ToExpression[Characters@b]]
```

**Method 2 using If/Then for 45 char**

```
StringJoin[If[# == "0", "1", "0"] & /@ Characters@b]
```

**Method 3, operating directly on the string, for 34 char**

```
StringReplace[b, {"0" -> "1", "1" -> "0"}]
```

I suspect some Mathematica wizard is going to breeze in here and do it in 15 bytes.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman within Mathematica, each of the -> right arrows become single →s. My character count is correct. Mathematica preps copied code for pasting by adding spaces and replacing Unicode with ASCII characters, hence the representation above.

Comment: We count in bytes, not characters. `→` is 3 bytes.

Comment: And, they're snippets as opposed to functions or complete programs. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32365215#32365215

Answer (score 0):

## , 13 chars / 23 bytes

```
ô⟦ï]ć⇝a^1)ø⬯)
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin//interpreter.html?eval=false&input=1001&code=%C3%B4%E2%9F%A6%C3%AF%5D%C4%87%E2%87%9Da%5E1%29%C3%B8%E2%AC%AF%29)</kbd>

Comment: I think this is technically invalid, because the language was invented after the challenge.

Comment: But it doesn't have any advantage specific to the challenge...

Answer (score 0):

## [TeaScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TeaScript), 8 bytes

```
xl(#l^1)

x       //input
 l(#    //loops through every character of the input
    l^1 //find the inverse of each character
       )
```

Try it online at its [online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/?code=xl%28%23l%5E1%29&input=10101110101010010100010001010110101001010) interpreter (**DOES NOT WORK IN CHROME**).

Comment: With TeaScript 3 this can be `xl#l^1`

Answer (score 0):

## C, 42 bytes

```
main(c){for(;c=~getchar();putchar(~c^1));}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 48 bytes

```
$<.each_char{|i|print (i.ord-1).chr.gsub"/","1"}
```

Not the shortest, but somewhat interesting

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 57 bytes

```
print(''.join(['0' if i=='1' else '1' for i in input()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 8 bytes

```
VwpCxCN1

Vw       for every char in input
     CN  compute char code of char
    x  1 xor with 1
   C     convert from int to char
  p      print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [pb](https://esolangs.org/wiki/pb), 46 bytes (non-competing)

```
^w[B!0]{w[B=48]{vb[1]^b[0]}>}vw[X!0]{<b[48+B]}
```

pb is newer than this challenge is, so it can't compete. Oh well.

In pb, the input lives at Y=-1. This program loops over the whole input, putting a 1 below any bytes in the input with a value of 48, or '0'. At the end of the input, it goes back to Y=0 and heads right, adding 48 to everything. Spaces that were left alone become 48=='0', spaces with a 1 value become 49=='1'.

**Explained:**

```
^w[B!0]{        # For each byte of input:
    w[B=48]{      # While byte == '0':
        vb[1]^      # Place a 1 on the canvas below it
        b[0]        # Clear input char (just to break loop)
    }
>}

vw[X!0]{<       # For each point on the canvas below the input:
    b[48+B]       # Add 48 to the existing value (convert digit to ASCII)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Beam](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beam), 54 bytes

While I having some fun playing with beam, hears the shortest I've managed to do for this one so far.  All the unused spaces are a wee bit annoying, but I might be able to compress this a wee bit more.

```
'''''''>`+++++\
v+<--n<rSP(++ /
 Hu(`<
(@   r^
>@pS r^
```

Boiled down it compares the the ascii value of STDIN to the ascii value of 1 and decrements if 1 or increments otherwise.  It doesn't throw errors or anything if non zeros or ones are encountered.

Try it in the snippet

```js
var ITERS_PER_SEC = 100000;
var TIMEOUT_SECS = 50;
var ERROR_INTERRUPT = "Interrupted by user";
var ERROR_TIMEOUT = "Maximum iterations exceeded";
var ERROR_LOSTINSPACE = "Beam is lost in space";

var code, store, beam, ip_x, ip_y, dir, input_ptr, mem;
var input, timeout, width, iterations, running;

function clear_output() {
document.getElementById("output").value = "";
document.getElementById("stderr").innerHTML = "";
}

function stop() {
running = false;
document.getElementById("run").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("clear").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("timeout").disabled = false;
}

function interrupt() {
error(ERROR_INTERRUPT);
}

function error(msg) {
document.getElementById("stderr").innerHTML = msg;
stop();
}

function run() {
clear_output();
document.getElementById("run").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("clear").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("input").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("timeout").disabled = false;

code = document.getElementById("code").value;
input = document.getElementById("input").value;
timeout = document.getElementById("timeout").checked;
 
code = code.split("\n");
width = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < code.length; ++i){
 if (code[i].length > width){ 
  width = code[i].length;
 }
}
console.log(code);
console.log(width);
 
running = true;
dir = 0;
ip_x = 0;
ip_y = 0;
input_ptr = 0;
beam = 0;
store = 0;
mem = [];
 
input = input.split("").map(function (s) {
  return s.charCodeAt(0);
 });
 
iterations = 0;

beam_iter();
}

function beam_iter() {
while (running) {
 var inst; 
 try {
  inst = code[ip_y][ip_x];
 }
 catch(err) {
  inst = "";
 }
 switch (inst) {
  case ">":
   dir = 0;
   break;
  case "<":
   dir = 1;
   break;
  case "^":
   dir = 2;
   break;
  case "v":
   dir = 3;
   break;
  case "+":
   if(++beam > 255)
    beam = 0;
   break;
  case "-":
   if(--beam < 0)
    beam = 255;
   break;
  case "@":
   document.getElementById("output").value += String.fromCharCode(beam);
   break;
  case ":":
   document.getElementById("output").value += beam;
   break;
  case "/":
   dir ^= 2;
   break;
  case "\\":
   dir ^= 3;
   break;
  case "!":
   if (beam != 0) {
    dir ^= 1;
   }
   break;
  case "?":
   if (beam == 0) {
    dir ^= 1;
   }
   break;
  case "_":
   switch (dir) {
   case 2:
    dir = 3;
    break;
   case 3:
    dir = 2;
    break;
   }
   break;
  case "|":
   switch (dir) {
   case 0:
    dir = 1;
    break;
   case 1:
    dir = 0;
    break;
   }
   break;
  case "H":
   stop();
   break;
  case "S":
   store = beam;
   break;
  case "L":
   beam = store;
   break;
  case "s":
   mem[beam] = store;
   break;
  case "g":
   store = mem[beam];
   break;
  case "P":
   mem[store] = beam;
   break;
  case "p":
   beam = mem[store];
   break;
  case "u":
   if (beam != store) {
    dir = 2;
   }
   break;
  case "n":
   if (beam != store) {
    dir = 3;
   }
   break;
  case "`":
   --store;
   break;
  case "'":
   ++store;
   break;
  case ")":
   if (store != 0) {
    dir = 1;
   }
   break;
  case "(":
   if (store != 0) {
    dir = 0;
   }
   break;
  case "r":
   if (input_ptr >= input.length) {
    beam = 0;
   } else {
    beam = input[input_ptr];
    ++input_ptr;
   }
   break;
  }
 // Move instruction pointer
 switch (dir) {
  case 0:
   ip_x++;
   break;
  case 1:
   ip_x--;
   break;
  case 2:
   ip_y--;
   break;
  case 3:
   ip_y++;
   break;
 }
 if (running && (ip_x < 0 || ip_y < 0 || ip_x >= width || ip_y >= code.length)) {
  error(ERROR_LOSTINSPACE);
 }
 ++iterations;
 if (iterations > ITERS_PER_SEC * TIMEOUT_SECS) {
  error(ERROR_TIMEOUT);
 }
}
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Code:
    <br>
    <textarea id="code" rows="8" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;width:90%;">'''''''>`+++++\
v+<--n<rSP(++ /
 Hu(`<
(@   r^
>@pS r^</textarea>
    <br>Input:
    <br>
    <textarea id="input" rows="2" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;width:90%;">10101110101010010100010001010110101001010</textarea>
    <p>Timeout:
        <input id="timeout" type="checkbox" checked="checked">&nbsp;
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id="run" type="button" value="Run" onclick="run()">
        <input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="interrupt()" disabled="disabled">
        <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear_output()">&nbsp; <span id="stderr" style="color:red"></span>
    </p>Output:
    <br>
    <textarea id="output" rows="6" style="overflow:scroll;width:90%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 81 Bytes:

```
function(s){return s.replace(/1/g,'a').replace(/0/g,'b').replace(/a/g,0).replace(/b/g,1)}
```

### Test

`=>`"1001101"

`<=`"0110010"

Comment: `function(s){return s.replace(/1/g,'a').replace(/0/g,'1').replace(/a/g,'0')}` is shorter.

Comment: @mbomb007 Oh thanks! I didn't notice that redundancy in mine. Mind if I add that to my original post?

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 41 bytes

```
(fn[b](apply str(map #(if(= %\1)\0\1)b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 34 bytes

```
|*(* `tape`(turn +< (cury mix 1)))
```

Stole Dennis' method for using `char xor 1` to switch between '0' and '1'.

Return a gate that maps over the tape given, and calls `(mix n 1)` (binary xor) for each element, then cast the resulting list back to a tape.

In Hoon, the entire memory model is a binary tree of bignums. All code is evaluated on this tree, called the 'subject'. `+<` is "tree navigation syntax"; instead of specifying a name for the compiler to resolve into an axis of the subject, you can provide the axis yourself with alternating characters of `+`/`-` and `<`/`>` to walk the tree. Code within a gate is evaluated on a subject that has the arguments it was called with placed at `+<`, so we can reference the arguments directly without having to assign a name to them.

`|*` creates a wet gate, essentially a generic function, that is typechecked at the callsite with a monomorphized version of the gate. This lets us use `*` as the sample for the gate instead of having to use `|=(tape code)` - as long as the type of the arguments at the callee are a valid list, so that `++turn` typechecks.

```
> %.  "10101110101010010100010001010110101001010"
  |*(* `tape`(turn +< (cury mix 1)))
"01010001010101101011101110101001010110101"
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

as an anonymous function takes a string and returns a string

```
s=>s.Aggregate("",(a,b)=>a+(b>'0'?'0':'1'));
```

<s>or as an anonymous function takes a string and prints the inverted, also in 47 bytes</s>

```
s=>{foreach(var c in s)Write(c=='0'?'1':'0');};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3 (40 bytes)

As a closure expression that takes `x` as input and returns a String:

```
{x in String(cString:x.utf8.map{$0^1})}
```

### Explanation

```
// make a function…
let invert = { (x: String) in

  // …that will xor each UInt8 character in the input string
  let y = x.utf8.map { $0 ^ 1 }

  // …and create String from the resultant [UInt8]
  String(cString: y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gogh, 5 bytes

```
{n!}m
```

This takes the logical not of the integer value of each character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 55 bytes

```
a->a.replace('0','2').replace('1','0').replace('2','1')
```

This is a `java.util.function.UnaryFunction<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

## Turtlèd, 24 bytes (non-competing)

```
' !-[*+.(1'0r)(0'1r)_]'
```

[note trailing space]

beating the non golf langs, in a task this language is not really designed for :)

### Explanation

```
'[space]                      write space over initial square
  !                           take input into string variable
   -                          decrement the string pointer (used when writing char from string)
    [*               ]        while current cell is not *
      +.                      increment string pointer, write pointed char from string
        (1'0r)                if cell is 1, write 0, move right
              (0'1r)          if cell is 0, write 1, move right
                    _         EOF checker: if end of string var, write *, else [space]
                      '[space]write space on cell (asterisk must be here)
          [implicit]     remove trailing and leading spaces and newlines, print grid.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3 - <s>59</s> 41 bytes

( -18 bytes thanks to @Mego)

```
lambda s:''.join(str(1-int(c))for c in s)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This solution is valid in both Python 2 and Python 3. There's quite a few improvements you can make, though. 1) By using a lambda function instead of a named function, you can omit the `return` statement: `lambda s:''.join('1'if c=='0'else'0'for c in list(s))`. 2) Strings are iterable, so you can replace `list(s)` with simply `s`). 3) Using boolean arithmetic on integer values is shorter: `str(1-int(c))` instead of `'1'if c=='0'else'0'`. If you're willing to restrict your answer to Python 2 only, `\`1-int(c)\`` is even shorter.

Comment: How'd you know I'm new here! Thanks for your suggestions, editing my answer now! I'd rather keep it compatible to both py3 and py2 though.

Comment: I know you're new here because I found your answer in the review queue for answers posted by new users.

Answer (score 0):

## Reticular, 13 bytes

```
iSBl[:0Eo]~*;
```

[Try it online!](http://reticular.tryitonline.net/#code=aVNCbFs6MEVvXX4qOw&input=MTAxMDEwMTExMDEwMDEwMTAwMTAxMDE&args=)

#### Explanation

```
iSBl[:0Eo]~*;
i              take one line of input
 S             convert string to array of chars
  B            merge array with stack
   l           push the length
    [    ]~*   active the inside (length) times
     :0        push the string "0"
       E       check for equality
        o      output
            ;  terminate program
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 97 bytes

Inspired by a comment from 2 years ago @hdante ...

*Golfed version*:

```
String d(String s){String r="";for(int i=0;i<s.length();)r(s.charAt(i++)=='0')?"1":"0";return r;}
```

*Ungolfed version*:

```
String d(String s)
{
    String r = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length();)
        r += (s.charAt(i++) == '0') ? "1" : "0";
    return r;
}
```

Nothing too fancy ...

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge 98, 13 bytes

```
#@~1+:'1`2*-,
```

Increments each character, and substracts 2 if the result is greater than '1' (using a multiply instead of a conditional, i.e. using *2 * <greater than '1'>*).

Commented version:

```
v / Skip the next byte
  |
  |/ End
  ||
  ||/ getc, reflect IP on EOF
  |||
  |||/ push 1
  ||||
  ||||/ add
  |||||
  |||||/ duplicate TOS
  ||||||
  ||||||/ character literal
  |||||||
  |||||||/ push '1'
  ||||||||
  ||||||||/ greater than
  |||||||||
  |||||||||/ push 2
  ||||||||||
  ||||||||||/ multiply
  |||||||||||
  |||||||||||/ substract
  ||||||||||||
  ||||||||||||/ putc
  |||||||||||||
> #@~1+:'1`2*-,
```

Answer (score 0):

## Binary-Encoded [Golfical](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Golfical), 31 bytes

Noncompeting, language postdates the question.

This encoding can be converted back to Golfical's standard graphical format using the encoder/decoder provided in the Golfical github repo, or run directly by using the `-x` flag.

Hex dump of binary encoding:

```
00 80 03 00 30 14 14 0C 01 14 14 1B 14 1A 16 14
14 26 14 14 25 1B 14 00 30 00 31 17 1C 1C 1D
```

Original image:

[image]

Scaled up 45x:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 61 bytes + 3 for `-v1` flag

```
#S::((replace S (regex "\\d" "g") (js-bridge #X::((^ X 1)))))
```

Requires the `-v1` flag to `run.js`, as `js-bridge` is not part of the standard library yet.

Exploits the JavaScript's `String.replace` function by passing a bridge function, allowing Lithp code to handle the replacement.

Usage:

```
(
    (def i #S::((replace S (regex "\\d" "g") (js-bridge #N::((^ N 1))))))
    (print (i "01010101111000"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 39 bytes

Taking input from stdin and printing to stdout:

```python
for c in input():print(1-int(c),end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Logicode](http://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode), 9 bytes

```
out ~ainp
```

[Try it online!](http://logicode.tryitonline.net/#code=b3V0IH5haW5w&input=MTAwMA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 39 bytes

```
s->{for(int i=s.length;i-->0;)s[i]^=1;}
```

### Testing

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Pcg30361 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Consumer<char[]> f = s->{for(int i=s.length;i-->0;)s[i]^=1;};

    char[] s = "10101110101010010100010001010110101001010".toCharArray();

    char[] expected = "01010001010101101011101110101001010110101".toCharArray();

    f.accept(s);
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(s, expected));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5,   54 Bytes

```
print(''.join('1'if a=='0' else '0' for a in input()))
```

Much longer now ;-; (but it depends how you interpret the Q, invert can mean "reverse" as well as "opposite")

Comment: This is problematic for two reasons. 1) doesn't do what the challenge asks this reverses a binary string instead of inverting it, 2) it assumes input from a predefined variable which is not considered a valid form of input, [relevant meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Comment: "Invert" has more than one possible interpretation, so it's a simple mistake. Other than that, your right, changes'll be applied later

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 69 bytes

Full Program:

```
b=raw_input();a=''
for i in b:
    if i=='1':a+='0'
    else:a+='1'
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8m2KLE8PjOvoLREQ9M60VZdnSstv0ghUyEzTyHJioszM00h09ZW3VDdKlHbVt1AnYszNac4FcwxVOcqKMrMK1FI/P/f0AAIDcEkEEIIKAZJwEUhAAA)

Comment: Its not clear from the specifications but this probably doesn't do what the question wants.  It does not work on the one test case provided.

Comment: @WheatWizard- My bad. I didn't understand the question. Correcting it.

Comment: I wouldn't say its your bad, the question is extremely unclear, only providing a test case.

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 7 bytes

```
dn&,{_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/JU9Npzq@9v///4YGQGgIJoEQQkAxSAIh@jUvXzc5MTkjFQA)

Kinda non-competing because braingolf *cannot* accept integer input from command-line arguments, it will always implicitly convert it to an integer if the input is only digits.

### Explanation

```
dn&,{_}  Implicit input from command-line args
d        Split number into digits
 n       Negate, all truthy values become 0, all falsey values become 1
  &,     Flip entire stack
    {_}  Print each item
```

## Old [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 12 bytes

```
i{#0-}n&,{_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/s1rZQLc2T02nOr72/39DAyA0BJNACCGgGCSBEP2al6@bnJickQoA)

### Explanation

```
i{#0-}n&,{_}
i             Read line from STDIN, convert each char to ordinal and push to stack
 {...}        Foreach, runs on each item in stack
  #0-         Subtract 48 from each ordinal
      n       Negate, all truthy values become 0, all falsey values become 1
       &,     Flip entire stack
         {_}  Print each item
```

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 8 bytes

**Solution:**

```
"01""0"=
```

**Example:**

```
q)"01""0"="1010101100010011"
"0101010011101100"
```

**Explanation:**

Same vein as the J answers, use a boolean list to index into an array of `"01"`

```
/ return list of bools where list = "0" (thus inverted)
q)"0"="1010101100010011"
0101010011101100b
/ index into array of "01" at indexes 0 or 1
q)"01" 0101010011101100b
"0101010011101100"
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 39 bytes

```
void f(string s){for(v:s)cout<<(v<49);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 12 bytes

```
'0:~\-!+:,j@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X93Aqi5GV1HbSifL4f9/QwNDIDIwAAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Check](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/check-lang), 27 bytes

Non-competing as language postdates the question.

```
   :,r>#v
#d=!pd)##.:+&:R-?
```

Check is my new esolang. It uses a combination of 2D and 1D semantics. Stack manipulation is done in 1D, while control flow is done in 2D.

This program assumes that the input bits were passed as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 6 bytes

```
,i!ipO
```

Read a character, cast it to an int, negate it, cast it to an int again, print it, and go back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 6 bytes

```
A~ae*f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/37EuMVUr7f9/QyAwAAJDEASyAA)

```
A       Take bit 0x01 of input
 ~      Invert it
  a     Set bit 0x01 of output to that value
    *   Provide a constant 1 value to neighbors
   e f  Set bits 0x10 and 0x20 to 1
```

So, in English, this prints '0' if the low bit of input is on, and '1' if the low bit is off.

(Chip is a 2D language, which is why the `*` sends a signal both left and right. It sends the same up and down too. `a` and `e` don't interact, so no whitespace is needed there.)

We can handle raw binary data too, in 31 bytes:

```
A~a B~b C~c D~d E~e F~f G~g H~h
```

This simply inverts all bits.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 38 bytes

```
INPUT S$WHILE""<S$?SHIFT(S$)<"1";
WEND
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 29 bytes

```
./""|map("\(1-tonumber)")|add
```

Expanded

```
  ./""                   # split into array of one character strings
| map("\(1-tonumber)")   # invert each element
| add                    # join array back into a single string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8r2RoAISGYBIIIQQUgyQQokoKNf/19JWUanITCzSUYjQMdUvy80pzk1KLNJU0axJTUv7//5dfUJKZn1f8X1c3rzQnRzczr6C0BMgpSizXzS8tAXIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/j-uby), 14 bytes

```
~:tr&'01'&'10'
```

equivalent to `lambda { |x| x.tr("01","10")}`; literally replaces `1` with `0` and `0` with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## SQL 2017, 35 bytes

[The `TRANSLATE` keyword](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) is only available starting in SQL 2017 (is the "non-competing" rule still a thing?), and replaces all instances of characters from the second string with the corresponding character in the third.

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(a,'01','10')FROM t
```

Input is via pre-existing table `t`, [per our input standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

The triple replace for older SQL versions is nearly twice as long (**65 bytes**):

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(a,'0','2'),'1','0'),'2','1')FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 5 bytes

```
³n¬w;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///Q5rxDa8qt////r25gCIQGYBIIIQQUgyQQouoA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 23 bytes

```lua
join(a|"."|#floor(1-a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z8rPzNPI7FGSU@pRjktJz@/SMNQN1FT8////0qGBkBoCCaBEEJAMUgCIaoEAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [OML](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/OML), 10 bytes

```
1(j1^oee)L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/N@f/fUCPLMC4/NVXTB8g2MDA0AAA)

### Explanation

```
1(j1^oee)L
1(    ee)    while stdin is not empty
  j          take a character of input
   1^        xor it with 1
     o       and output it
        L    clear the stack (stack is displayed implicitly otherwise)
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 49 bytes,

```
bitwXor(strtoi(unlist(strsplit(scan(,""),""))),1)
```

Not the shortest answer, but eh !

Here, we :

- take as input the sequence as a character string `scan(,"")`,
- split it into its digits `strsplit(x, "")`, creating a list (an **R** object),
- flatten the list `unlist(x)`, creating a vector (another **R** object).

The items in the vector are converted to integers `strtoi`, on which the **XOR** logical operation is applied `bitwXor`, with respect to `1`.

Here we're taking advantage of **R**'s recycling. Both elements of the fonction `bitwXor` are vectors, but have different length. The function reuse the shortest vector to apply the operation to each element of the longest vector.

---

Briefly, **XOR** (⊕) table of truth is :

1 ⊕ 1 = 0
1 ⊕ 0 = 1
0 ⊕ 1 = 1
0 ⊕ 0 = 0

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 15 Bytes

```
y=StrReverse(x)
```

Assuming that x is a String Input, [StrReverse Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e462ax87(v=vs.90).aspx) can be used and the output is y As String. (Credit: [Grant Peters](https://superuser.com/a/415540/717860))

A code to test the result:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As String, y As String
    x = "10101110101010010100010001010110101001010"
    y = StrReverse(x)
    Debug.Print y
    'Output: 01010010101101010001000101001010101110101
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 5 Bytes

That is, if array input is allowed:

```
i=:-.
```

Defines the verb i to be the 'not' function.

If string input is mandatory, there's this 10 byte solution:

```
i=:-.@"."0
```

If string *output* is also mandatory, there's this 18 byte solution:

```
i=:,@:(":@-.@"."0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
ＦθＩ¬Ｉι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBo1BTIaAoM69EwzmxuETDLx/KyNQEAuv//w0NgNAQTAIhhIBikARC9L9uWQ4A)

Link is to the verbose version of the code. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ             for each character in the input as string
                implicitly print
      Ｉι       the character as a number,
     ¬          inverted
   Ｉ           and casted again as string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 10 bytes

Or is it 01 bytes?

```
~O!-84i@j~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/7/OX1HXwiTTIavu/39DAyA0BJNACCGgGCSBEAUA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 39 bytes

```cs
b=>b.Aggregate("",(c,d)=>c+(char)(d^1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrgOh7BJt/yfZ2iXpOaanF6WmJ5akaigp6Wgk66Ro2tola2skZyQWaWqkxBlqav635goAainRSNRQMjSAQCBS0tS0/g8A)

Shortest of all the C# solutions! You can make it even shorter with Select instead of Aggregate if the rules allow you to return a sequence of chars instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 4 bytes

```
÷(¬"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////8HaNQ2uU/v83NDA0AAA)

- `÷` splits the number into individual bits
- `(` does the following `length of stack` times
- .... `¬` logically not the top
- .... `"` right shifts to the next item

Uses latest github interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 9 bytes

```
ir['0=up]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zKFrdwLa0IPb/fwNDAwgyNAQA)

Pretty straightforward this time...

```
i         - read in the input a codepoints
 r        - reverse the stack
  [     ] - loop until the stack is empty
   '0=    - compare to "0"
      u   - write the test results out 0=1, 1=0
       p  - pop the
```

Answer (score -1):

## TI-BASIC, 3 bytes

```
B=0
```

Same "feature" as J; assuming the binary is stored in `B`, it will display the output. Here is an explanation:

> The TI-BASIC comparison operator is =. However, = doesn't work like the normal == operator: it compares item-by-item. Keep in mind that an array is formed like this: {0,2,3}. `2={0,2,3}` returns `{0,1,0}` for example. Since TI-BASIC's bools are 1 and 0, this results in a list of 1's and 0's (They aren't strings, and every other character other than 1 would also result in 0.)

Comment: As a side note, `not(B` would do the same thing.

Comment: Works only on lists, not strings; B isn't even a list or string variable.

Answer (score -1):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), 3 bytes

Given the input as a boolean list:

```
not
```

## k, 1 byte

```
~
```

Logical [not](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/not/) operator