# Convert a program to a palindromic program

Tags: code-golf, palindrome

A *palindrome* is a string that is the same forwards and backwards, such as "racecar".

Write a program in some language L, that takes any program P1 in language L as input, and outputs a palindromic program P2 in language L that does the same thing as P1.

You do not need to worry about handling input programs with syntax errors.

This is **code golf**, so the solution with the fewest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Can we define the language L?

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes. L is the language you choose to write your program in.

Comment: In some languages, this is surprisingly tough.

Comment: With a turing complete subset of Python, this is a valid entry: `x=input();print(x+'#'+x[::-1])`. The subset is the set of all programs that don't include newlines.

Answer (score 17):

## Perl, <strike>55</strike> 54 bytes

```perl
undef$/;$a=<>."\n__END__\n";print$a,scalar reverse$a;
```

Reads program source from stdin and writes to stdout.

Result of running on itself:

```perl
undef$/;$a=<>."\n__END__\n";print$a,scalar reverse$a;

__END__

__DNE__

;a$esrever ralacs,a$tnirp;"n\__DNE__n\".><=a$;/$fednu
```

Comment: +1 for not using comments

Comment: I like that it marks the apparent gibberish at the bottom with "DNE" - a common shorthand for "Do Not Erase" used to mark things on chalkboards/whiteboards so that people don't mistake them for unimportant scribblings and wipe them off.

Comment: how does it work, I don't know perl, more specifically how does it quine(get the line that it's reversing)?

Comment: @Cruncher: `__END__` indicates the end of the parseable portion of the script. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__END__.html For input, `<>` reads the input from stdin.

Comment: @GregHewgill the program source is read through stdin? That's odd. I assume that nothing after __END__ goes through this stream then?

Comment: @Cruncher: The program doesn't read its *own* source. The program takes whatever input you give to it. You can give it itself as input, which is what I did for the example.

Comment: @GregHewgill I misunderstood the question a bit. I got it now. I thought it was supposed to palindromize itself

Comment: 1+ Works in most cases except when program ends with `__DATA__` that is read.. eg. `print while(<DATA>);\n__DATA__` will change behaviour.

Comment: @Sylwester: True. This works for the subset of Perl scripts that don't use `__DATA__`. :)

Answer (score 11):

## Java, 225 bytes

```java
class c{public static void main(String[]a){String s="";java.util.Scanner r=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);while(r.hasNext())s+=r.nextLine()+"\n";s=s.replace("\n","//\n");System.out.print(s+new StringBuilder(s).reverse());}}
```

Output on itself (when prettified beforehand):

```java
class c {//
    public static void main(String[] a) {//
        String s = "";//
        java.util.Scanner r = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);//
        while (r.hasNext()) s += r.nextLine() + "\n";//
        s = s.replace("\n", "//\n");//
        System.out.print(s + new StringBuilder(s).reverse());//
    }//
}//

//}
//}
//;))(esrever.)s(redliuBgnirtS wen + s(tnirp.tuo.metsyS        
//;)"n\//" ,"n\"(ecalper.s = s        
//;"n\" + )(eniLtxen.r =+ s ))(txeNsah.r( elihw        
//;)ni.metsyS(rennacS.litu.avaj wen = r rennacS.litu.avaj        
//;"" = s gnirtS        
//{ )a ][gnirtS(niam diov citats cilbup    
//{ c ssalc
```

Comment: Problem if comment ending in *. See [comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31439#comment67326_31478)

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, 68 bytes

```python
import sys
x=''.join(l[:-1]+'#\n'for l in sys.stdin)
print x+x[::-1]
```

Doesn't work if run from IDLE, because you need to generate an EOF character to stop the program from waiting on input.

Output when run on itself:

```python
import sys#
x=''.join(l[:-1]+'#\n'for l in sys.stdin)#
print(x+x[::-1])#

#)]1-::[x+x(tnirp
#)nidts.sys ni l rof'n\#'+]1-:[l(nioj.''=x
#sys tropmi
```

Thanks to Greg Hewgill for helping to hammer out problems and to golf.

Comment: Nice job, beats my kinda lame Python attempt.

Comment: @GregHewgill I prefer a nice upvote to a nice comment ;-)

Comment: Ok okay... I don't usually vote against myself. :)

Comment: @GregHewgill I vote "against" myself **a lot**. I upvote answers based on their merits, not based on whether or not I answered.

Answer (score 9):

## GolfScript, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
"
}"+.-1%
```

Quite similar to [minitech's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31448), but it works well with newlines. It relies on GolfScript's funny (and undocumented) behavior to ignore an unmatched (and uncommented) `}`, as well as everything that follows it.

It will fail if the input contains an unmatched `{`, but that would technically constitute a syntax error.

#### How it works

```
"
}"   # Push the string "\n}".
+    # Concatenate it with the input string.
.    # Duplicate the modified string.
-1%  # Reverse the copy.
```

## Example

```
$ echo -n '1{"race{car"}
> {"foo\"bar"}
> if#' | golfscript make-palindrome.gs
1{"race{car"}
{"foo\"bar"}
if#
}}
#fi
}"rab"\oof"{
}"rac{ecar"{1
$ echo '1{"race{car"}
> {"foo\"bar"}
> if#
> }}
> #fi
> }"rab"\oof"{
> }"rac{ecar"{1' | golfscript
race{car
```

Comment: Try `1\n2#` (`\n` would be an actual newline character) as your input.

Comment: @Quincunx: Pesky comments... A newline before the curly bracket should fix that.

Comment: Before **and** after. Need to remain a palindrome.

Comment: @Quincunx: Of course. It should work now.

Answer (score 5):

### x86 machine code on DOS (`.com` file) - 70 bytes

Dealing with .COM files, creating a palyndrome is easy - since the COM "loader" just puts the content of the file at address `100h` and jumps there, the program must already hardcode its end somehow and ignore everything after it, so we can just append the reverse of the first N-1 bytes (only caveat: if the program somehow tries to do tricks with the length of file everything breaks).

Here is the hex dump of my `.COM`-palyndromizing `.COM`:

```
00000000  31 db 8a 1e 80 00 c6 87  81 00 00 ba 82 00 b8 00  |1...............|
00000010  3d cd 21 72 30 89 c6 bf  ff ff b9 01 00 ba fe 00  |=.!r0...........|
00000020  89 f3 b4 3f cd 21 3c 01  75 18 b4 40 bb 01 00 cd  |...?.!<.u..@....|
00000030  21 85 ff 75 e5 89 f3 f7  d9 88 ee b8 01 42 cd 21  |!..u.........B.!|
00000040  eb d8 47 74 f0 c3                                 |..Gt..|
```

It takes the input file on the command line, and writes the output on stdout; the expected usage is something like `compalyn source.com > out.com`.

Commented assembly:

```
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    ; NUL-terminate the command line
    xor bx,bx
    mov bl, byte[80h]
    mov byte[81h+bx],0
    ; open the input file
    mov dx,82h
    mov ax,3d00h
    int 21h
    ; in case of error (missing file, etc.) quit
    jc end
    ; si: source file handle
    mov si,ax
    ; di: iteration flag
    ; -1 => straight pass, 0 reverse pass
    mov di,-1
loop:
    ; we read one byte at time at a bizarre memory
    ; location (so that dl is already at -2 later - we shave one byte)
    mov cx,1
    mov dx,0feh
    mov bx,si
    mov ah,3fh
    int 21h
    ; if we didn't read 1 byte it means we either got to EOF
    ; or sought before the start of file
    cmp al,1
    jne out
    ; write the byte on stdout
    mov ah,40h
    mov bx,1
    int 21h
    ; if we are at the first pass we go on normally
    test di,di
    jnz loop
back:
    ; otherwise, we have to seek back
    mov bx,si
    ; one byte shorter than mov cx,-1
    neg cx
    ; dl is already at -2, fix dh so cx:dx = -2
    mov dh,ch
    mov ax,4201h
    int 21h
    jmp loop
out:
    ; next iteration
    inc di
    ; if it's not zero we already did the reverse pass
    jz back
end:
    ret
```

Tested on itself and the [solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31405/9298) to a previous question seems to work fine in DosBox, some more extensive testing on "canonical" DOS executables will follow.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript, 8

```
.-1%'#'\
```

Doesn’t handle newlines, but nobody uses those in GolfScript.

Comment: Using newline in string literals can be used quite often ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash+coreutils, 39 bytes

```
f="`cat`
exit"
echo "$f"
tac<<<"$f"|rev
```

Reads from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT:

```
$ cat hello.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello, World!'

$ ./palin.sh < hello.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello, World!'
exit
tixe
'!dlroW ,olleH' ohce

hsab/nib/!#
$
```

Comment: @user23013  Seems to work fine.  At least a simple test like `( echo 'Hello, World!' )`.  bash pretty much ignores everything after the `exit`.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (*ES6*) Multi-line - 71

Kinda sorta stole [Quincunx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9498/quincunx)'s comment method here:

```javascript
alert((x=prompt().replace(/\n/g,'//\n')+'/')+[...x].reverse().join(''))
```

## Single line - 49

```javascript
alert((x=prompt()+'/')+[...x].reverse().join(''))
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <strike>214</strike> 209 bytes

```c
#include<cstdio>
#include<stack>
int main(){std::stack<char>s;int c;while((c=getc(stdin))>EOF){if(c=='\n')for(int i=2;i;i--)s.push(putchar('/'));s.push(putchar(c));}while(s.size()){putchar(s.top());s.pop();}}
```

Result of running on itself:

```c
#include<cstdio>//
#include<stack>//
int main(){std::stack<char>s;int c;while((c=getc(stdin))>EOF){if(c=='\n')for(int i=2;i;i--)s.push(putchar('/'));s.push(putchar(c));}while(s.size()){putchar(s.top());s.pop();}}//

//}};)(pop.s;))(pot.s(rahctup{))(ezis.s(elihw};))c(rahctup(hsup.s;))'/'(rahctup(hsup.s)--i;i;2=i tni(rof)'n\'==c(fi{)FOE>))nidts(cteg=c((elihw;c tni;s>rahc<kcats::dts{)(niam tni
//>kcats<edulcni#
//>oidtsc<edulcni#
```

Comment: Fail when continuation char '\' is used. Try [http://ideone.com/TCZHr9]

Comment: @edc65: Yeah, I thought about that later. The only obvious way I can think of to handle that would be to unfold the folded lines first.

Comment: can be done at small cost - se my C answer

Answer (score 2):

## C 168 <s>175</s>

Correctly handles escaped newline inside source code

**Edit 1** fixed bug when last newline missing
**Edit 2** fixed bug when line inside comment ends with `*`: add a tab char before the `//` comment  
(and golfed more)

```
b[999999];main(c,z){char*p,for(p=b;(*p=c=getchar())>=0;z=c,p++)c-10||(z-92?*p++=9,*p++=47,*p++=47,*p=c:(p-=2));*p=47;for(p=b;*p;)putchar(*p++);for(;p>b;)putchar(*--p);}
```

C99 Standard, valid code, many warnings

**Ungolfed**

```
b[999999]; // working buffer ~ 4M on 32 bit machine, max source size
// c is current char, z is previous char,
main(c,z) // z  start as argv pointer, will be out of char range
{
  char *p;
  for(p = b; 
      (*p=c=getchar()) >= 0; // while testing EOF copy char to buffer set c variable
      z=c, p++) // at end loop increment p and set previous = current
  {
      c-'\n' || // if newline 
       (z - '\\' // check if escaped
          ? *p++='\t',*p++='/',*p++='/', *p=c // if not escaped, add tab,/,/ and newline
          : (p-=2) // if escaped, drop both escape and newline
       ); 
  }
  *p='/'; // if last newline missing, will add a comment anyway
  for(p=b;*p;) putchar(*p++); // ouput buffer 
  for(;--p>=b;) putchar(*p); // outbut buffer reversed
}
```

Comment: there is a little bug in it. try `/* *<NL>
*/int main(){}`

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 749 without whitespace (not golfed)

This produces brainfuck programs which mirrored palindromes, i.e. they are are mirror images of themselves.

```
++++++++++
[->++++>+++++++++<<]>+++.>+..<.>++.
>>>>+[>,]<-[+<-]
>[
  [-<+<<+>>>]
  +<-------------------------------------------[-<+>>[-]<]>[-<<<.>>>]
  +<<-[->+>[-]<<]>>[-<<<.>>>]
  +<-[-<+>>[-]<]>[-<<<.>>>]
  +<<-[->+>[-]<<]>>[-<<<.>>>]
  +<--------------[-<+>>[-]<]>[-<<<.>>>]
  +<<--[->+>[-]<<]>>[-<<<.>>>]
  +<-----------------------------[-<+>>[-]<]>[-<<<.>>>]
  +<<--[->+>[-]<<]>>[-<<<.>>>]
  <[-]>>
]
<<<<[<]
<--.<.>++..--..<.>++.
>>[>]
<[
  [->+>>+<<<]
  +>-------------------------------------------[->+<<[-]>]<[->>>.<<<]
  +>>-[-<+<[-]>>]<<[->>>.<<<]
  +>-[->+<<[-]>]<[->>>.<<<]
  +>>-[-<+<[-]>>]<<[->>>.<<<]
  +>--------------[->+<<[-]>]<[->>>++.--<<<]
  +>>--[-<+<[-]>>]<<[->>>--.++<<<]
  +>-----------------------------[->+<<[-]>]<[->>>++.--<<<]
  +>>--[-<+<[-]>>]<<[->>>--.++<<<]
  >[-]<<
]
<--.<.>++..<.
```

Given a program it outputs

```
+[[+]PROGRAM[+]][[+]MIRROR[+]]+
```

with `PROGRAM` and `MIRROR` replaced by the program (without non-brainfuck characters) and its mirror image.

Answer (score 1):

## C# - 174

```
using System;using System.Linq;class c{public static void Main(){var a="";var b="";while((a=Console.ReadLine())!="")b+=a+"//\n";Console.Write(b+string.Concat(b.Reverse()));}}
```

Test Input:

```
using System; 
using System.Linq; 
class c 
{ 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        var a = ""; 
        var b = ""; 
        while ((a = Console.ReadLine()) != "") 
            b += a + "//\n"; 
        Console.Write(b+string.Concat(b.Reverse())); 
    } 
}
```

Test Output:

```
using System; 
using System.Linq; 
class c 
{ 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        var a = ""; 
        var b = ""; 
        while ((a = Console.ReadLine()) != "") 
            b += a + "//\n"; 
        Console.Write(b+string.Concat(b.Reverse())); 
    } 
} 

// }
// }
// ;)))(esreveR.b(tacnoC.gnirts+b(etirW.elosnoC
// ;"n\//" + a =+ b
// )"" =! ))(eniLdaeR.elosnoC = a(( elihw
// ;"" = b rav
// ;"" = a rav
// {
// )(niaM diov citats cilbup
// {
// c ssalc
// ;qniL.metsyS gnisu
// ;metsyS gnisu
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood one of the instructions. Your program should be able to take *any* program as input, and write out a palindromic program that does the same thing as the original program.

Comment: It can.. If I input the C++ code from your answer, it returns exactly what you have.

Comment: All your program does is reverse its input. The output of your program is not a complete palindromic program.

Comment: Oh yeah, i get ya. Updated - better now?

Comment: Well, almost. Now it works for *your* program (with the `//` at the end of each line), but would not work for any other program. It's a very simple change to make it work from this point, though.

Comment: Ahh yes. added it. `//\n`

Comment: Yup, that's it. Your test output should have the `//` at the end of each line now though.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 96 bytes

```
function a($b){
    echo $c = "a('$b')" . strrev("a)'" . $b . "'(");
    $d = substr($c, 0, strlen($b) + 5);
    eval("$d;");
}
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
a('apple'); // echoes a('apple')('elppa')a until your bytes get exhausted
```

This is nothing clever. It's just a simple piece of code that does the job... I was in a mood for playing. 
I do know that this code is rife with bad programming practices!

Finally, I will gladly accept any criticism and edits to this code!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. This is a function, not a program. See the other answers, they provide good examples.

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 134

```cobra
class P
    def main
        i=List<of String?>(Console.readLine.split('\n'))
        print '/#\n[i.reversed.join("\n")]\n#/#\n[i.join("\n")]\n#/'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket 133

```scm
(require srfi/13)(let((r read-line)(w display))(let l((i(r)))(when
(not(eq? eof i))(w i)(w";\n")(l(r))(w"\n;")(w(string-reverse i)))))
```

Ungolfed (but still very imperative):

```scm
(require srfi/13)
(let recurse ((instr (read-line)))
  (when (not (eof-object? instr))
    (display instr)
    (display ";\n")
    (recurse (read-line))
    (display "\n;")
    (display (string-reverse instr))))
```

Output when given the ungolfed version as input:

```scm
(require srfi/13);
(let recurse ((instr (read-line)));
  (when (not(eof-object? instr));
    (display instr);
    (display ";\n");
    (recurse (read-line));
    (display "\n;");
    (display (string-reverse instr))));

;))))rtsni esrever-gnirts( yalpsid(    
;)";n\" yalpsid(    
;))enil-daer( esrucer(    
;)"n\;" yalpsid(    
;)rtsni yalpsid(    
;))rtsni ?tcejbo-foe(ton( nehw(  
;)))enil-daer( rtsni(( esrucer tel(
;)31/ifrs eriuqer(
```