# Is my name official?

Tags: code-golf, string

#### Introduction

[As ToonAlfrink says](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30361/the-shortest-code-to-invert-a-binary-string): "Me thinks there aren't enough easy questions on here that beginners can attempt!". So the task is very simple. Given a string, output a truthy or falsy value whether the name is official or not.

**A name is "official" if it is a single title-case word, that is:**

- If the *first* letter is capitalized (not official: `adnan`)
- If the other letters are *not* capitalized (not official: `AdNaN`)
- If the name *doesn't* contain any non-alphabetic characters (not official: `Adnan123`, `Adnan!`)
- If the name consists of just one word (not official: `Adn an`, `Adn An`)
- If the name has more than one character (not official: `A`)

#### Rules

- You may provide a function or a program
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!
- **Note:** To simplify things, names like Mary-Ann are in this challenge *not official.*
- Assume that there are no leading whitespaces in the name.
- Assume that only the printable ASCII characters (`32-126`) are used in the names

#### Test cases

```
Input: Adnan
Output: True

Input: adnan
Output: False

Input: AdnaN
Output: False

Input: Adnan123
Output: False

Input: Adnan Adnan
Output: False

Input: A
Output: False

Input: Mary-Ann
Output: False
```

#### Leaderboard

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 67554; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 34388; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So my name's not official? I'd better change it then.

Comment: @ETHproductions If we're using this logic, `Lololololololololololol` is an official name :)

Comment: I don't think ETHproductions would be official, since there are capitalized letters beyond the first one. What's the definition of an "alphabetic character"? Is it only the 26 letters of the English alphabet? Or also letters from other languages? Like German names with umlauts, or French/Spanish names with various accents?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Only the basic Latin characters are used

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Which is it: "you may assume the name doesn't contain accented letters", or "names with accented letters should yield `False`"?

Comment: What, your name consist of only one syllable? Then is it first name or last name? How about McDonald? Is it official

Comment: @Mauris Accented letters won't be even used in the name

Comment: Just because the explanation doesn't quite fit the challenge doesn't mean the challenge is wrong. It means the *explanation* is wrong. You can criticize the explanation once you come up with a better one, and **only then**.

Comment: As a slightly offbeat Canadian digression, a professor I know wouldn't be happy with your "official" criteria: [Robert Smith?](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/). His name _actually does have that question mark_. Also, [Sahaiʔa](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/north/chipewyan-baby-name-not-allowed-on-n-w-t-birth-certificate-1.2984173).

Comment: Are regexes allowed?

Comment: @FarhanAnam Yes

Comment: @Adnan And are using external frameworks allowed? Like .NET  (I guess it has to be for C#). And will the code need to include the `imports`/`usings`?

Comment: @FarhanAnam External frameworks are allowed. `imports` and `using` needs to be included in the code

Comment: This made trying to find all posts started by you significantly more difficult.

Comment: Is the name guaranteed not to be empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*Thanks to @Thomas Kwa for reminding me about titlecase.*

```
&qzr@GrzZ3tz
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26qzr%40GrzZ3tz&input=Adnan&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Adnan%0Aadnan%0AAdnaN%0AAdnan123%0AAdnan+Adnan%0AA%0AMary-Ann&debug=0).

```
&              Boolean and operator
 qz            Equality test on input
  r    3       Titlecase operator
   @G          Setwise intersection with the alphabet
    rzZ        Input to lowercase
 tz            All but the first character of the input
```

Answer (score 21):

## Retina, 13 bytes

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+$
```

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XltBLVpdW2Etel0rJA&input=QWRuYW4) | [Test suite](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWBeW0EtWl1bYS16XSsk&input=YWRuYW4KQWRuYU4KQWRuYW4xMjMKQWRuYW4gQWRuYW4KQQpNYXJ5LUFubg) (The output `0` means none of the strings matched, which is expected.)

When Retina is only provided with a single line of code, it outputs the number of times the expression matched the input string, so it will output `1` (truthy) if it matches and therefore is an official name and `0` (falsy) if it's not.

#### Breakdown

```
^       The beginning of the string
[A-Z]   One uppercase letter
[a-z]+  One or more lowercase letters
$       The end of the string
```

Comment: Looks like we need character classes for letters. ;)

Answer (score 9):

## TeaScript, 12 bytes

```
xO`A-Z][a-z`
```

Abuses the `O` function.

[Try this online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22xO%60A-Z%5D%5Ba-z%60%22&inputs=%5B%22Vihan%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

[Test Suite](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22xs%C2%A7.m(%23(x%3Dl,%20%60$%7Bl%7D:%20$%7BxO%60A-Z%5D%5Ba-z%60%7D%60))j%C2%A7%22&inputs=%5B%22Adnan%5Cnadnan%5CnAdnaN%5CnAdnan123%5CnAdnan%20Adnan%5CnA%5CnMary-Ann%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

### Explanation

The `O` function makes this:

```
x O   `A-Z][a-z`
x.O(/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/)
```

Then, the O function checks if the regex matches `x`.

---

Alternatively, a  TeaScript 3 answer at **7 bytes**:

```
xO/\A\a
```

Comment: Ahahaha, nice one. At some point while I was working on the Japt interpreter, I used this trick with the `isChar` function you added. But you may want to explain in more detail for those not in the know.

Comment: Ooooooh, I like the new regex features!

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 26

```
n=>/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test(n)
```

By: Edcsixtyfive

```js
f=n=>/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test(n)

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;['Adnan','adnan','AdnaN','Adnan123','Adnan Adnan','A','Mary-Ann']
.forEach(t=>console.log(t+' '+f(t)))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it. You also outgolfed my version by 5 bytes.

Comment: One byte less: `n=>n.match\`^[A-Z][a-z]+$\``

Comment: @user81655 an array as a truthy value is too forced IMHO

Comment: @edc65 It is valid though.

Comment: For only 4 bytes more you get ES5 compliance: `/./.test.bind(/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/)`

Comment: @CRDrost post it as a ES5 solution (pls with an explanation)

Comment: Wrote this exact code before even looking at the answers, knowing full well someone else would have already done it lol... Well done =)

Comment: Does `/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test` work? i.e. `n=/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test;n(str)`?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere nice idea, worth a try, but it does not

Answer (score 7):

## Python, <s>59</s> 58 bytes

I'm sure there's no real way to beat the Retina version, since this is basically just that within Python. But I think this is my first submission ;)

```
import re,sys;print(re.match('[A-Z][a-z]+$',sys.argv[1]))
```

It's a very *odd* truthy value:

```
(test2)wayne@arglefraster ~/programming/inactive/golf/67554
⚘ python golf.py AdNan                                                                                                 $? 148  %# 3  10:06:36
None
(test2)wayne@arglefraster ~/programming/inactive/golf/67554
⚘ python golf.py Adnan                                                                                                         %# 3  10:06:40
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7feefea7f440>
(test2)wayne@arglefraster ~/programming/inactive/golf/67554
⚘ python golf.py "Adnan Banana"                                                                                                %# 3  10:06:47
None
```

(And it does require `""` around strings with spaces in it, if passed via the shell)

Comment: `^` is not needed as `re.match()` only matches at the beginning of string.

Comment: @manatwork nice! Another byte shaved :) I could save another byte with the closing paren, using Python2

Comment: @WayneWerner: that's why you should give the Python version :) I think Python 2 and Python 3 are kind of different languages, at least for codegolf.

Comment: If you use a anonymous lambda instead of a whole program, you get 45 bytes: `lambda s:re.match('[A-Z][a-z]+$',s)
import re`

Comment: @movatica Immediately what I was thinking. You could even use `from re import*` for less bytes

Comment: @MilkyWay90: nope, in this case this costs more than it saves: `re.` is 3 bytes vs `from *` which counts 6.

Comment: @movatica Oh, whoops!

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 53 bytes

```
boolean b(String a){return a.matches("[A-Z][a-z]+");}
```

Comment: You can use a lambda: `s->s.matches("[A-Z][a-z]+")`

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>50</s> <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
lambda s:s.isalpha()*s.istitle()*len(s)>1
```

Returns `True` if it's an official name or `False` if it's not.

Comment: Rules of codegolf state, that you don't need to take the `f=` into account, saving two bytes. Also, `(len(s)>1)` saves 5 bytes over `s[1:].islower()`. :)

Answer (score 3):

## VB6, 48 bytes

```
Function f(i):f=i Like"[A-Z][a-z]+":End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

## [BotEngine](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Bot-Engine), <s>203</s> <s>180</s> 29x6=174

```
v ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>ISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSF
v <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 Tabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSF
^E<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

I should really add builtins for identifying uppercase and lowercase letters. That would be much more concise than checking each letter individually.

Rough translation:

```
for a of input enqueue a
if ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ contains first
 remove first
 while abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz contains first
  remove first
 if empty
  yield TRUE exit
 else
  yield FALSE exit
else
 yield FALSE exit
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, <strike>129</strike> <strike>122</strike> <strike>121</strike> 111 bytes

```
main(c,b,d){b=d=0;while((c=getchar())>13)b|=b|=!b&&c>90|c<65?1:2&&d++&&c<97|c>122?4:2;printf("%d\n",b<3&&d>1);}
```

[Try It Online](https://ideone.com/xaQPoR)

```
main(c,b,d)
{
    b=d=0;
    while((c=getchar())>13)
    {
        // Twiddle bits, 1<<0 for first character and 1<<3 for subsequent
        b|=!b&&c>90|c<65?1:2; // check first character is valid
        b|=d++&&c<97|c>122?4:2; // check later characters are valid
    }
    // If all OK b == 2, if either of above are wrong, b >= 3 due to 
    // extra bits. Also, d should be > 1 for name length to be valid.
    printf("%d\n",b<3&&d>1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 28 bytes

```
p (gets=~/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/)!=p
```

-2 bytes( thanks to manatwork )

Comment: Take a look at [Fábio Perez](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7027/f%c3%a1bio-perez)'s [`p` related tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9268) in [Tips for golfing in Ruby](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby).

Comment: Simpler and shorter:  `p !!gets[/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/]`

Comment: 20 using `-n`, `p~/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/!=p`. [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6eUuyCpaUlaboWWwrq9OOiHXWjYqMTdatitVX0FW0LIFJQFQtuWjmm5CXmcSWCSRDbD0zmGRoZQxgKEAWOXL6JRZW6jnl5XP5paZnJmYk5ECMA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
á™Q×¦Ā
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MJHLYsCD08/tOxIw///jgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCf8PL3zUsijw8PRDy440/Nf5H63kmJKXmKeko6CUCGe4@Dn6gRiOKbpQIZAiPxgjz9DIGM5WgOt3BBG@iUWVuo55YAGf/BxkqBQLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
á       # Only leave the letters of the (implicit) input
        #  i.e. "Adnan" → "Adnan"
        #  i.e. "A" → "A"
        #  i.e. "aDNAN" → "aDNAN"
        #  i.e. "Adnan123" → "Adnan"
 ™      # Titlecase it
        #  i.e. "Adnan" → "Adnan"
        #  i.e. "Adnan" → "A"
        #  i.e. "aDNAN" → "Adnan"
  Q     # Check if it's still equal to the (implicit) input
        #  i.e. "Adnan" and "Adnan" → 1 (truthy)
        #  i.e. "A" and "A" → 1 (truthy)
        #  i.e. "aDNAN" and "Adnan" → 0 (falsey)
        #  i.e. "Adnan123" and "Adnan" → 0 (falsey)
   ×    # Repeat the (implicit) input that many times
        #  i.e. "Adnan" and 1 → "Adnan"
        #  i.e. "A" and 1  → "A"
        #  i.e. "aDNAN" and 0 → ""
        #  i.e. "Adnan123" and 0 → ""
    ¦Ā  # Remove the first character, and check that it's non-empty
        #  i.e. "Adnan" → "dnan" → 1 (truthy)
        #  i.e. "A" → "" → 0 (falsey)
        #  i.e. "" → "" → 0 (falsey)
        # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: 7 bytes: `á™Qиg2@`

Comment: @Grimy Thanks, but the `и` should be `×` instead. By using `и` you create a list with the string in it, so the length of that list is always 1 regardless of the string length.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 10.1, 46 bytes

```
LetterQ@#&&#==ToCamelCase@#&&StringLength@#>1&
```

Uses one less byte than the standard regex solution. It does three checks. `LetterQ@#` ensures that the string is entirely composed of letters, and `StringLength@#>1` invalidates single-letter strings. `#==ToCamelCase@#` makes less sense, however. `ToCamelCase` is an undocumented function I found that takes an input string AndOutputsItLikeThis. Since there is only one word, it will capitalize the first letter, so we check if the string is equal to that.

Comment: Is `ToCamelCase` new in 10.3? Doesn't seem to work in 10.2.

Comment: @murphy, it works for me in 10.1. What do you get with `ToCamelCase["foo bar baz"]`?

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that it works in 10.1. However, in 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 and 10.2 the function is not defined (your test case returns `ToCamelCase[foo bar baz]`). Strange! Maybe someone can check 10.3?

Answer (score 2):

### bash/zsh/ksh, 25 bytes

```
[[ $1 =~ ^[A-Z][a-z]+$ ]]
```

To actually use this, make a file with it as the only line and make the file executable; executable files not recognized as a known binary type are treated as shell scripts (for `/bin/sh` specifically).

```
$ printf '[[ $1 =~ ^[A-Z][a-z]+$ ]]' >f
$ chmod +x f
$ wc -c f
25 f
$ for x in 'Adnan' 'adnan' 'AdnaN' 'Adnan123' 'Adnan Adnan' 'A' 'Mary-Ann'; do f "$x" && echo 1 || echo 0; done
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
$
```

Comment: This works fine in `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`, but has no chance to work in standard POSIX `sh` or the compatible `dash` and `yash`. To avoid confusion, I suggest to change the answer's title.

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `echo` to create the file and you’ll get 25 bytes.

Comment: Good points, both of you; both applied.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 18 bytes

The current version ([4.0.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/4.0.0)) of the language is used.

This applies the same regular expression as [NinjaBearMonkey's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67555/36398):

```
j'^[A-Z][a-z]+$'XX
```

The output is the string (which [is truthy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/36398)) if it's an official name, and nothing (which [is falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/36398)) if it's not.

#### Examples

```
>> matl
 > j'^[A-Z][a-z]+$'XX
 > 
> December
December
>> 

>> matl
 > j'^[A-Z][a-z]+$'XX
 > 
> ASCII
>>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 61 bytes

```
f(h:t@(_:_))=elem h['A'..'Z']&&all(`elem`['a'..'z'])t
f _=1<0
```

Comment: [One byte fewer](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00jw6rEQSPeKl5TsyY1JzVXISNa3VFdT089Sj3WNjEnRyMBJJoQrZ4IEqxSj9Us4UpTiLc1tDH4n5uYmWerUFCUmVeioKKQpqDkATQzX@k/AA)

Comment: [Several more down](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00jw6rEQSPeKl5Ts0bdQd0mQyfDRj1a3TYxJ0cjITUnNTchWj1RXU9PvUo9VrOEK00h3tbQxuB/bmJmnq1CSj6XgkJBUWZeiYKKQpqCkgfQzHyl/wA). You could also use that technique for the other test to be more efficient, but it's the same number of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Gema, 17 characters

```
\B<K1><J>\E=1
*=0
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n 'Adnan' | gema '\B<K1><J>\E=1;*=0'
1

bash-4.3$ echo -n 'adnan' | gema '\B<K1><J>\E=1;*=0'
0

bash-4.3$ echo -n 'Adnan123' | gema '\B<K1><J>\E=1;*=0'
0
```

Answer (score 2):

## IA-32 machine code, 19 bytes

A function that receives the pointer to a null-terminating string in `ecx` and returns 0 or 1 in `eax` (according to the `fastcall` convention).

Hexdump of the code:

```
6a 20 58 32 01 74 0a 41 2c 61 3c 1a b0 00 72 f3 c3 40 c3
```

In assembly language:

```
    push 32;
    pop eax;

myloop:
    xor al, [ecx];
    jz yes;
    inc ecx;
    sub al, 'a';
    cmp al, 26;
    mov al, 0;
    jb myloop;
    ret;

yes:
    inc eax;
    ret;
```

The first byte of the input name has its 5th bit flipped (`xor` with `32`) to convert it from capital case to small case. This loads 32 into `eax`, using 3 bytes of code:

```
    push 32;
    pop eax;
```

To check whether the byte is a small letter:

```
    sub al, 'a';
    cmp al, 26;
    jb myloop;
```

If not, this code falls through. To return 0 in this case, it puts 0 in `al` before doing the conditional jump:

```
    sub al, 'a';
    cmp al, 26;
    mov al, 0;
    jb myloop;
```

The 0 in `al` also serves as a xor-mask (or absence of it) for the following bytes of the input name.

A successful exit is when it encounters a zero byte, which stays zero after the `xor`:

```
    xor al, [ecx];
    jz yes;
```

It assumes that the input name is not empty. I guess it's a reasonable assumption about a name (not an arbitrary string)!

Answer (score 2):

#### `grep`, 16 bytes

This is the pattern:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+
```

If you use the `-E` and `-x` and `-c` switches `grep` will print a count of matching input lines. So if you give it one line you get a 1 or a 0. I think that's how this place works.

The pattern is 11 chars, the whole command line is 23. I've seen people use `sed` scripts without the command so I don't know what is what. But, it reads stdin, and so you can just type at it. Here's `echo`:

```
for a in Adnan adnan Ad\ nan
do  echo "$a" | grep -cxE \[A-Z]\[a-z]+
done
```

---

```
1
0
0
```

Comment: @Doorknob - seems fair enough to me. thanks very much. which hat did you guess?

Comment: I figured out Hairboat's Revenge. :P

Comment: Stop me if (as is quite probable) I'm wrong but you can use `grep -Exc` so you don't need to count as many bytes for the switches.

Comment: @Neil - i dunno if you're wrong. i have really no idea - have a look at the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

### C# 4, 89 bytes

My first attempt at Code Golf. Here it comes:

```
bool o(string i){return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(i,"^[A-Z][a-z]+$");}
```

See it in action at [Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CulhZw).

Comment: If you use C# 6, you can make it a bit shorter: `bool o(string i)=>System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(i,"^[A-Z][a-z]+$");`

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 28 bytes

```
n->n.matches("[A-Z][a-z]+")
```

Uses regex to make sure the string consists of an uppercase character followed by at least one lowercase character.

-1 bytes thanks to Benjamin Urquhart

Comment: You can drop the semicolon

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart oh right, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
Lċ?₍ǐǍ≈∧
```

[Try it Online (with test cases)!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiTMSLP+KCjceQx43iiYjiiKciLCIiLCJBZG5hblxuRW1pcnBzXG5Kb2huXG5hZG5hblxuQWRuYU5cbkFkbmFuMTIzXG5BZG5hbiBBZG5hblxuQVxuTWFyeS1Bbm4iXQ==)

Potentially golfable. I swear there was a builtin for `len(a)>1`...

Assumes input is nonempty.

```
L        # Length of input
 ċ       # is not 1
  ?      # Push the input,
   ₍     # parallel apply...
    ǐ    # title case and
     Ǎ   # keep only alphabetic chars
      ≈  # is equal?
       ∧ # bitwise AND the length and ^
```

Comment: [6 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwix43HkD0q4bii4biDIiwiIiwiQWRuYW5cbkVtaXJwc1xuSm9oblxuYWRuYW5cbkFkbmFOXG5BZG5hbjEyM1xuQWRuYW4gQWRuYW5cbkFcbk1hcnktQW5uIl0=) (port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `b`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ịḟ=×ḣ
```

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
Ịḟ=×ḣ  # Implicit input
Ị      # Remove non-alphabets from the input
 ḟ     # Convert this string to title case
  =    # Check whether it's still equal to the input
   ×   # Repeat the input this many times
       # (i.e. input if true, empty string otherwise)
    ḣ  # Remove the first character from this string
       # The b flag boolifies the resulting string,
       # checking that it is not empty
       # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

(click to enlarge)

Answer (score 1):

### k4, 39 bytes

```
{((*x)in .Q.A)&(&/(1_,/x)in .Q.a)&1<#x}
```

First char is upper, all others are lower, count greater than one.

E.g.:

```
  {((*x)in .Q.A)&(&/(1_,/x)in .Q.a)&1<#x}'("Adnan";"adnan";"AdnaN";"Adnan123";"Adnan Adnan";"A";"Mary-Ann")
1000000b
```

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 16 bytes

```
ú4,nÿ=)l1<)ù-Y&&
```

Hex Dump:

```
a3342c6e983d296c313c29972d592626
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=a3342c6e983d296c313c29972d592626&input=Adnan)

Seriously does not have regex support yet, so the best we can do is:

```
 4,n                               Push 4 copies of input
    ÿ=                             Check that it's equal to itself converted to titlecase
      )                            Put the boolean on the bottom
       l1<                         Check that it's longer than 1 character
          )                        Put the boolean on the bottom
           ù                       Convert it to lowercase.
ú           -Y                     Check that removing the lowercase alphabet empties it
              &&                   And all the booleans together
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ocaml, <strike>231</strike> <strike>216</strike> <strike>197</strike> 166 bytes

```
let f n=let l=String.length n in if l=1 then 0 else let rec e=function 0->1|i->match n.[i] with('a'..'z')->e(i - 1)|_->0 in match n.[0]with('A'..'Z')->e(l - 1)|_->0;;
```

Example usage:

```
# f "Adnan";;
- : int = 1

# f "adnan";;
- : int = 0

# f "AdnaN";;
- : int = 0

# f "Adnan123";;
- : int = 0

# f "Adnan Adnan";;
- : int = 0

# f "A";;
- : int = 0

# f "Mary-Ann";;
- : int = 0
```

Ungolfed (with real function names):

```
let is_name name =
  let len = String.length name
  in if len = 1 then 0 else
  let rec explode_lower = function
    | 0 -> 1
    | i ->
      match name.[i] with
      | ('a'..'z') -> explode_lower (i - 1)
      | _ -> 0
  in match name.[0] with
  | ('A'..'Z') -> explode_lower (len - 1)
  | _ -> 0;;
```

Comment: You could actually save about 10% by using booleans instead of integers (bleh!) and replacing those bulky `if … then 0 else ` by `… ||`. And for that matter by using boolean operators instead of `match` and ranges, e.g. `n.[0]>'@'&n.[0]<'['&e(l-1)`

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 2, 116 bytes

Regex is so verbose in Swift that doing this is much shorter

```
func e(s:String)->Int{var c=0;for k in s.utf8{if(c==0 ?k<65||k>90:k<97||k>122){return 0};c++};return s.utf8.count-1}
```

This will return `0` or `-1` (in the case of no input) for non-official names, and a number `> 0` (which is equal to the length of the string - 1) if the name is official

#### Ungolfed

```
func e(s: String) -> Int{
    var c = 0
    for k in s.utf8{
        if(c == 0 ? k < 65 || k > 90 : k < 97 || k > 122){
            return 0
        }
        c++
    }
    return s.utf8.count - 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 39 bytes

SpecBAS handles regular expressions through the `MATCH` command. Output is 0 for false and 1 if true.

```
1 input n$:  ?MATCH("^[A-Z][a-z]+$",n$)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 188 bytes

Regular expressions would have been the right way to tackle this, but here's an attempt without it.

```
bool O(string s){for(int i=1;i<s.Length;i++){if(char.IsUpper(s[i])){return false;}}if(char.IsUpper(s[0])&&s.All(Char.IsLetter)&&!s.Contains(" ")&& s.Length > 1){return true;}return false;}
```

Longhand

```
static bool O(string s)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(s[i]) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (char.IsUpper(s[0]) && s.All(Char.IsLetter) && !s.Contains(" ") && s.Length > 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Would love advice on how to make the lowercase check shorter, perhaps without the loop. I just started learning the language, and used this as practice, figured I'd share my result anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 18 bytes

```perl
$_=/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/LtpRNyo2OlG3KlZbRf//f8eUvMQ8rkQwCWL7gck8QyNjCEMBosCRyzexqFLXMS/vX35BSWZ@XvF/3YIcAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 29 bytes

```powershell
"$args"-cmatch'^[A-Z][a-z]+$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9JJbEovVhJNzk3sSQ5Qz0u2lE3KjY6UbcqVltF/X8tFxeXkgdQcb6SjoJSBpwBIhxT8hLzDI2MIWwFxxQoIzERxPBNLKrUdczLS1VSqFFVqFZSiVewUlDRUFNJU1CJ11Sq/Q8A)

Does the same regex trick everyone else is using. Has to use `c`ase-sensitive `match` to properly do it at the cost of a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 17 bytes

```perl6
{/^<:Lu><:Ll>+$/}
```

Returns a `Match` object if this is an official name and `Nil` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v1o/zsbKp9QOSOTYaavo1/635krLL1KwsXFMyUvMU0gEkyC2H5jMMzQyVlByhIvmKSk4KvgmFlXqOubl2dkpVHNxFidWKiipxCvYAnn2aQoq8bVK1ly1/wE)

Comment: You don't need the `m`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

Returns `1` or `0`.

```
è"^%A%a+$
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=6CJeJUElYSsk&input=IkFkbmFuIg)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 18 bytes

```
'[A-Z][a-z]+'&rxeq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxST3aUTcqNjpRtypWW12tqCK1ECJxs1WTKzU5I18hTUHdMSUvMU9BHc5PBPHVUaT9ULl5hkbGaCIKjmi6EEzfxKJKXcc8JEn_tLTM5MzEHHWIYxYsgNAA)

```
'[A-Z][a-z]+'&rxeq
              rxeq  NB. does the regex fully describe the string
             &      NB. bind the left argument to
'[A-Z][a-z]+'       NB. the Official™ regex
```

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, 15 bytes or 37 bytes (rule dependent)

### Flexibly truthy

If you're allowed to define "truthy" as "non-empty string", then:

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fPy7aUTcqNjpRtypWW0X//3/HlLzEPK5EMAli@4HJPEMjYwhDAaLAkcs3sahS1zEvDwA)

### Strict truthy

If it needs to be something more consistent like 1 and 0, then:

```
{print match($0,/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/)?1:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uqAoM69EITexJDlDQ8VARz8u2lE3KjY6UbcqVltFX9Pe0Mqg9v9/x5S8xDyuRDAJYvuByTxDI2MIQwGiwJHLN7GoUtcxLw8A)

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 73 bytes

Good old `#define`

```cpp
#include<regex>
#define F(s)std::regex_match(s,std::regex("[A-Z][a-z]+"))
```

Code to test :

```cpp
std::cout << F("Adnan") << '\n';
std::cout << F("adnan") << '\n';
std::cout << F("AdnaN") << '\n';
std::cout << F("Adnan123") << '\n';
std::cout << F("Adnan Adnan") << '\n';
std::cout << F("A") << '\n';
std::cout << F("Mary-Ann") << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript(ES6), 83 bytes

```
s=>s[0].match(/[A-Z]/)&&s.substr(1).match(/[a-z]/)&&!s.match(/[^A-Z]/i)&&s.length>1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü╡♫╒┤á╕◘▓
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81b50ed5b4a0b808b2&i=Adnan%0Aadnan%0AAdnaN%0AAdnan123%0AAdnan+Adnan%0AA%0AMary-Ann&a=1&m=2)

Tests for complete match with regex `"[A-Z][a-z]+"`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) 98 bytes

```
x.length>1 && x.mapIndexed{i,c->if(i>0)c in 'a'..'z' else c in 'A'..'Z'}.sumBy{if(it) 0 else 1}==0
```

Way less boring than shorter:

```
x.matches(Regex("[A-Z][a-z]+"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZExb4MwEIV3fsWVIdhSg6DdkEAiUitFVdshnbpdwBCr5kBgVKeI305NE7VZgurN77v33ln@qLWSNBU9gWEm2ulWUsmjTV0rgQTxZHwlqNSHJITVCoxfYbOlXBiRD/I2WyeyYDIJeAaSwEPP970vD4TqBJykdJbevdHv@mpzHOZxzSE4jYRjHAc/5dh1otVvbS/YPoJzPYfBAXtkAexmz0Ef2voTtkqJEtVOoxYPJhONljUx7oyO85f0iDb/StR/kyqU9nY2XixomJvmhORyfoFOjZbhApt9LwuMwrv7JQxLxekV/Rnb4zqlX1tj/1grYu7rk2sfO30D)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This code looks like a code snippet to me, but you need to provide a function or a full program, so you probably need to tack on that `fun x(x:String)=` part to your code for the actual score. Other than that, I'm sure there are a few spaces you can cut out, such as around `&&`, etc. to reduce your code size more!

Comment: As Java lambda were allowed, I have assumed that fun assignment were allowed too.

Comment: Lambdas in Java (and other languages) are allowed because variable assignment is not always necessary to run the function. [Using the Java answer in this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71881/52194) as an example, `list_of_inputs.stream().map(n->n.matches("[A-Z][a-z]+"))` is valid code; instead of assigning it to a variable the lambda is simply passed directly into a function argument. It works because that block of code has everything it needs to run (which variables are inputs, etc.)

Comment: Anyways, [I looked up how to use lambdas in Kotlin.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) You don't need to declare `fun` or the return type, just wrap it in `{x:String->yourcode}`! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZExb4MwEIV3fsWVIdhSg6DdkEAiUitFVdshnbpdwBCr5kBgVKeI305NE7VZgurN77v33ln@qLWSNBU9gWEm2ulWUsmjTV0rgQTxZHwlqNSHJITVCoxfYbOlXBiRD/I2WyeyYDIJeAaSwEPP970vD4TqBJykdJbevdHv@mpzHOZxzSE4jYRjHAc/5dh1otVvbS/YPoJzPYfBAXtkAexmz0Ef2voTtkqJEtVOoxYPJhONljUx7oyO85f0iDb/StR/kyqU9nY2XixomJvmhORyfoFOjZbhApt9LwuMwrv7JQxLxekV/Rnb4zqlX1tj/1grYu7rk2sfO30D "Kotlin – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 51 bytes

```php
<?=ucfirst($s=$argn)==$s&ctype_lower(substr($s,1));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJSep2CrkJaeWlKsERzi4umnaa1gbweUti1NTsssKi7RUCm2BSvTtLVVKVZLLqksSI3PyS9PLdIoLk0qLikCKtAx1NS0/v/fMSUvMQ8A)

No regex.  Input is `STDIN`, output to `STDOUT` is `'1'` for truthy and `'0'` for falsy.

```php
$ echo Adnan|php -F p.php
1
$ echo adnan|php -F p.php
0
$ echo AdnaN|php -F p.php
0
$ echo Adnan123|php -F p.php
0
$ echo Adnan Adnan|php -F p.php
0
$ echo A|php -F p.php
0
$ echo Mary-Ann|php -F p.php
0
$ echo Mary-ann|php -F p.php
0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda s:len(s)>1==s.isalpha()<s==s.title()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNCsMgEIXX7Slmp0IaSLoLteAB2gu0XUxJJIJOxHGT05u6qJvH9354cc/rRmOx@l08hu@MwJNfSLK6D1pz7xh9XFGqG1ebXfaLVMVuCSiAI3gJ0YEwMyFVwD/U5NmqYbw2hjY2VR6Y9oshEp/pfIrJUf49d2AlBVUO)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 28 bytes

```arturo
$=>[match?&{/^[A-Z][a-z]+$}]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Mkpnlh)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 29 bytes

```lua
s=...print(s==s:match'%u%l+')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FZPT6@gKDOvRKPY1rbYKjexJDlDXbVUNUdbXfP///@OKXmJeQA)