# Invert a boolean array

Tags: code-golf, array, logic

A nice simple one

## Input

Given a boolean array (Or an acceptable alternative), you can assume the array will never be more than 32 elements long.

```
[false, false, true, false, false]
```

## Output

Invert every element of the array and output it.

```
[true, true, false, true, true]
```

## Rules

- You can write a full program or just a function
- Standard loopholes apply
- Shortest code in bytes, per language, wins!

## Test cases

```
Input:
[true, false]
Output:
[false, true]

Input: //Example of acceptable alternative
[0,1,1]
Output:
[1,0,0]
```

Comment: How about arrays of `0` (false, all 0 bits) and `-1` (true, all 1 bits)?

Comment: @Lynn While it's the OPs decision, [I'd say it should be up to whether your language considers though truthy/falsy.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/8478)

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/30361/8478) (Given the simplicity of the core task, I'd say the differences in format are significant enough that these aren't duplicates.)

Comment: More than code golf this looks to me like: what is the not operator in your favourite language? Additional points if it works on lists.

Answer (score 30):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

Code:

```
_
```

Explanation:

```
_     # Logical not
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Xw&input=WzEsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDFd)

Comment: I love the explanation

Answer (score 15):

## Javascript ES6, 15 bytes

```
a=>a.map(b=>!b)
```

Not much explanation needed I guess

```js
f=
a=>a.map(b=>!b)

a.innerHTML = `[true, false, 1, 0] => ${ f([true, false, 1, 0]) }`
```

```html
<pre id=a>
```

Comment: Probably can't get shorter than that...

Comment: Would simply `map(b=>!b)` count?

Comment: @MatthewJensen no because `map` is a method and not a regular function

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
¬
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wqw&input=&args=MSwxLDAsMCwx)

`¬` is logical NOT (1 if false-y, else 0). `C` (“complement”, **1−z**) also works.

Comment: I think @Dennis is going to have a hard time outgolfing you.

Comment: @flawr It's just a matter of time before Dennis does it in 0 bytes or less.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer "0 bytes **or less**" hmm

Comment: @zdimension It's Dennis, he can do it shorter than you think (read the memes).

Answer (score 14):

## Matlab,  <s>4</s>  1 byte

This should be self explanatory.

```
~
```

Matlab has the one-byte negation operator `~`, if you want a function you can use `@not`.

Comment: get `@`rgument, `n`egate, `o`utput, `t`erminate, right?

Comment: Haha, right, I'm surprised you're so fluent in Matlab!

Comment: lol, this sounds like Borat "This should be self explanatory .... NOT"

Comment: surely `~` is an appropriate answer since it's an operator that receives an argument. I think `~[1,0,0,1,0]` is entirely appropriate.

Comment: besides, by that logic, you should be doing `f=@not` anyway.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Operator submissions are definitely valid (in some languages like Julia and Mathematica it's even common practice to define your own operators because that's shorter than defining your own function), but I'm sure flawr just doesn't want to invalidate my comment. ;)

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, 7 bytes

```
map not
```

Example:

```
Prelude> (map not) [False, True, True]
[True,False,False]
```

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis in the example, right?

Comment: I don’t, but I wanted to demonstrate in the example how my answer is a valid expression and not a snippet.

Comment: There was a suggested edit just now to make the code `not<$>`, but that’s not a valid expression; you can’t write `f = not<$>` and then `f [False, True, True]`; operator slices need parentheses around them, which would contribute towards the byte count.

Comment: and also you're not supposed to suggest code via edits anyway

Comment: Can you do `map(1-)` and use `[0,1,1]` instead of `[False, True, True]`?

Answer (score 11):

## R, 1 byte

```
!
```

Example:

```
> !c(TRUE, FALSE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

It also works with numerical input:

```
> !c(1, 0)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

We're not restricted to one-dimensional arrays, either. Let's make a matrix, and randomly populate it with 0s and 1s:

```
> mat = matrix(rbinom(16, 1, .5), ncol=4)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0
```

We can invert this just as easily:

```
> !mat
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

We can continue to do this for arbitrary numbers of dimensions. Here's an example on a four-dimensional array:

```
> bigarray = array(rbinom(32, 1, 0.5), dim=c(2,2,2,2))
> bigarray
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    0

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    1

> !bigarray
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE

, , 2, 1

      [,1] [,2]
[1,] FALSE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE

, , 1, 2

     [,1]  [,2]
[1,] TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE FALSE

, , 2, 2

      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

Doesn't work for characters, I'm afraid.

```
> !"Hello world"
Error in !"Hello world" : Invalid argument type.
```

Comment: To save on submitting identical answers, this also works in Julia (except it doesn't work on numeric input there)

Answer (score 11):

## C, 46 Bytes recursive version

```
f(char*s){*s?putchar(*s&72?*s:*s^1),f(++s):0;}
```

## C, 47 Bytes iterative version

```
f(char*s){for(;*s;putchar(*s&72?*s:*s^1),s++);}
```

Run using this main function

```
main(c,v)char**v;
{
    f(v[1]);
}
```

and input like this

```
a.exe [1,0,1,1,0]
[0,1,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Shorter than I expected to see for C!

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 1 byte

```
~
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=fg&input=WzAsMSwxLDAsMV0&args=)

`~` is the logical *not* and as many functions, it can also be applied to arrays/matrices.

Comment: Works in APL too.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 4 bytes

"French"/Unicode version:

```perl6
!«*
```

"Texas"/ASCII version:

```perl6
!<<*
```

Input is a single value which can be treated as a list.

This is a a [Whatever lambda (`*`)](https://docs.perl6.org/type/WhateverCode) with the [logical not prefix operator (`!`)](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/!) combined using [prefix hyper operator (`«`)](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/$LESS-THAN_SIGN$LESS-THAN_SIGN).

Effectively this is the same as:

```perl6
-> $_ { $_.values.hyper.map: &prefix:<!> }
# ( currently the Rakudo implementation doesn't actually do the ｢.hyper｣ call,
#   but prefix ｢«｣ is specifically designated for doing things in parallel )
```

### Usage:

```perl6
# pretend it's a method
say (True,False,True,True).&( !«* );
# (False True False False)

say ( !«* )( (False,False,True,False,False) );
# (True True False True True)


# give it a lexical name
my &list-invert = !«*;

#              v¯¯ a space is necessary here
say list-invert (True,False);
# (False True)

say (False,True).&list-invert;
# (True False)
```

Comment: I was just trying to puzzle out the same thing. I only got as far as `{!«@_}` :)

Comment: `!**` should work too

Answer (score 7):

## [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 9 bytes

```
,$:)%#$.,
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=LCQ6KSUjJC4s&input=MQoxCjAKMQowCg) Assumes newline-separated input with a trailing newline. Thanks to @MartinEnder for help with golfing.

This program's a bit weird for a Labyrinth program - it doesn't make use of the 2D nature of the language, and it actually bounces back and forth. On the first forward trip, we have:

```
[Moving rightward]
,            Read char c of input
 $           XOR c with implicit 0 at bottom of stack
  :)%        Calculate c % (c+1), erroring out if c == -1 from EOF, otherwise returns c
     #$      XOR with (length of stack == 1)
       .     Output (c^1) as char
        ,    Read newline

[Moving leftward]
       .     Output newline
      $      XOR two implicit 0s, stack [0]
    %#       Mod with (length of stack == 1), giving stack [0]
 $:)         Increment, duplicate then XOR, stack still [0]
,            Read char c of input
```

The next occurence of `$` then XORs the existing 0 on the stack with `c`, as opposed to an implicit 0 at the bottom of the stack like in the first run. Both situations leave the stack as `[c]`, and the program repeats thereafter.

Alternative 9-bytes:

```
,:):/$.:,
,::)/)$.,
,:):%)$.,
```

Comment: This forwards-backwards effect is really cool.

Comment: I like this answer. It's happy. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 7 bytes

```
Not/@#&
```

or without letters:

```
!#&/@#&
```

As for the syntactic sugar: `&` marks the right end of an unnamed function and has very low precedence. `#` refers to the first argument of the nearest and enclosing `&`. `!` is the operator for `Not`. So `!#&` is just an unnamed function that negates its argument, in other words its identical to the built-in `Not`. `/@` is the operator for `Map`. So the code would also be equivalent to the somewhat more readable `Map[Not, #]&`.

Comment: How the `!#&/@#&` am I supposed to read that? :)

Comment: @Lynn Does that help? :)

Comment: I'm surprised that `Not` isn't listable

Comment: @ASimmons Yeah so was I.

Answer (score 6):

## Python, <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

Thanks to Lynn for golfing off two bytes, and xnor and Mego for golfing off another.

```
lambda a:[b^1for b in a]
```

Comment: Arrays of `0`/`1` are allowed, and `1-b` is shorter than `not b`. I asked the OP if arrays of `0`/`-1` are allowed, in which case `~b` is even shorter.

Comment: b^1 also works.

Comment: @xnor And that would actually be better, because then the space before the `for` could be dropped.

Comment: I didn't realize that `1for` would be parsed as two separate tokens.  Huh, TIL.

Answer (score 6):

## J, 2 bytes

```
-.
```

This is the negation verb.

### Test case

```
   -. 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 6):

## C#, 19 bytes

as an annonymous function, takes a bool[] and returns an IEnumerable

```
b=>b.Select(x=>!x);
```

or in 36 bytes with

```
dynamic f(bool[]b)=>b.Select(x=>!x);
```

Answer (score 6):

## Swift 3 (7 bytes)

```
.map(!)
```

e.g.

```
[true, false].map(!)
```

### Explanation

Seems pretty obvious. Calls `map` on the array `[true, false]`. The one "gotcha" is that, in Swift, operators are just functions and can be passed around as arguments. This means `map(!)` is passing the "not" function `!` into `map`.

Comment: An impressively short answer for a language that is terrible for golfing in. :)

Comment: I feel like I broke a rule or something. I'm not sure how these are judged. :D

Comment: This is awesome.

Answer (score 6):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Shakespeare), 240 bytes

```
.
Ajax,.
Puck,.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Ajax and Puck]
Puck:
Open your mind.Is hog as big as you?If so, let us return to scene II.You be sum of difference of zero and you and cat.Open thy heart!Let us return to scene I.
Scene II:.
[Exeunt]
```

Takes input as a string of `\0` and `\1` control characters. Outputs as a string of `0` or `1`. If the input must be the same as the output, replace `Open thy heart` with `Speak thy mind` for no change in bytecount. If `\0` and `\1` can't be used, do the above, but also replace `Open your mind` with `Listen to thy heart` for a 5-byte penalty.

Ungolfed:

```
The Invertion of Veronan Arrays.

Romeo, who stores the element.
Juliet, who lectures him.

Act I: In which an array is inverted.

Scene I: A silent entrance.

[Enter Romeo and Juliet]

Scene II: In which Juliet pours out her heart to Romeo.

Juliet:
  Open your mind. Is nothing better than thee? If so, let us proceed to scene III. 
  Thou art as good as the sum of the difference between nothing and thee and my 
  cat. Open your heart! Let us return to scene II.

Scene III: Finale.

[Exeunt]
```

This roughly translates to the following C pseudocode:

```
int romeo;

Scene1:
romeo = getchar();
if (0 > romeo) goto Scene2;
romeo = 0 - romeo + 1;
printf("%d", romeo);
goto Scene1;

Scene2:;
```

I'm using [this interpreter](http://github.com/drsam94/Spl). Sample run:

```
$ python splc.py invert.spl > invert.c
$ gcc invert.c -o invert.exe
$ echo -ne "\x00\x01\x00" | ./invert
101
```

Answer (score 5):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 2 bytes

```
!a
```

Usage:

Create a Notes form with two fields named a and b.

a (input) = editable, number, multi-value, comma separated

b (output) = computed, number, multi-value, comma separated

Paste the above formula into b and give a a default value of 0.

Create a new document with the form, enter a binary list in a and press F9 to update the output.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Works because given a list as input, Notes formula will apply whatever specified action to every element in the list.

Comment: Oh my god... My company just switched away from lotus notes; I had hoped to never see it again. +1 for that throwback.

Comment: I think many companies are @carusocomputing and probably rightly so. I've been working with it on and off for over 20 years and it still amazes me what formula language can do with list iterations sometimes. It's fun to open up designer occasionally and see how much I can still remember :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [JAISBaL](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL), 1 byte

```
!
```

Like all the other 1-byte answers, this is the negation operator, which can operate over an array if needed. This leaves the output on the stack, which is printed at the end of the program.

For two bytes, the array can be explicitly printed:

```
!§
```

Input is in JAISBaL's incredibly odd array format (which I did invent, but I don't like it...).

Test Cases (Output from the Java interpreter, 3.0.5):

```
Enter a value > [true][false]


--------------------
Stack: [[false, true]]
Locals: {}
----------------------------------------
Enter a value > [false][false][true][false][false]


--------------------
Stack: [[true, true, false, true, true]]
Locals: {}
```

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, 15 bytes

```
$args[0]|%{!$_}
```

I *think* this may even work in v1, hence I left the version number off the title. Loops through the input `$args` and negates each item in turn. That resulting array is left on the pipeline.

The neat thing, however, is because PowerShell is so loose on its casting requirements, you can do a completely mixed input and get an appropriate Boolean output. For example, here are the literal Boolean values `$false`/`$true`, the numbers `0` `1` and `123456789` as integers, an empty string, a non-empty string, an empty array, and a non-empty array --

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\invert-a-boolean-array.ps1 @($false,$true,0,1,123456789,'','foo',@(),@(1,1))
True
False
True
False
False
True
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 7 bytes

Includes +2 for `-lp`

Give each boolean value as 0 or 1 on its own line

```
invert.pl
1
1
0
^D
```

`invert.pl`:

```
#!/us/bin/perl -lp
$_^=1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Logicode](https://github.com/LogicodeLang/Logicode), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
out!binp
```

Simple, really.

Takes input as a binary string, as Logicode doesn't have support for lists (so `[true, false]` would be `10`).

The `out` outputs the line's result.

The `!` command calculates the NOT of every bit in the string, so something like `!111` would be `000`.

The `binp` is binary input.

1 byte saved thanks to @daHugLenny

Comment: I think you can remove the space between `out` and `!binp`.

Comment: @daHugLenny Huh, I was not aware you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
:{-$_}a
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OnstJF99YQ&input=WzE6MDowOjE6MDoxXQ&args=Wg&debug=on)

#### Explanation

```
:{   }a   Apply this predicate to each element of the Input
  -         Decrement
   $_       Negate
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 58 bytes

```
void f(boolean[]a){for(boolean i:a)System.out.print(!i);}
```

Comment: Ways to golf: change `arr` to `a` (saves 4 bytes), write `int[]a` instead of `int a[]` (saves 1 byte),

Comment: oops! how do i forget it?how insane i am. and thanks @OlivierGrégoire

Answer (score 3):

## Cheddar, 10 bytes

```
@.map((!))
```

I hope I counted right as I'm writing from phone

Comment: I think, equivalently, `fn.vec((!))`, if that was ever released :P

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck (58 Bytes)

```
-[>+<-----]>--->,[<[->->+<<]>[--<]>[>]<[-<+<+>>]<+.[-]<>,]
```

[Try it here](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LVs-KzwtLS0tLV0-LS0tPixbPFstPi0-Kzw8XT5bLS08XT5bPl08Wy08KzwrPj5dPCsuWy1dPD4sXQ&input=MTAwMTExMA)

Ungolfed

```
-[>+<-----]>---     Number 48 (stands for 0)
>,                  Read in first point
[               
    <[->->+<<]      Subtract 1 from 48 flag, subtract 1 from read data, add 1 for new flag
    >           
    [--<]           If sitting on 1 (true) subtract 2 and move left)
        >[>]<       Move to 48 flag
        [-<+<+>>]   Add 48 to data point
        <+.[-]<     Add 1 move print, zero cell, move to new 48 cell
        >,          Read in next point
]                   Loop if input remaining
```

Takes an input of undivided 1s or 0s (11001).

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 15 bytes

```
s->s.map(b->!b)
```

Note: `s` is a `java.util.stream.Stream<Boolean>` and the import is not necessary, proof below.

### Testing and ungolfed

**LookMaNoImports.java**

```
class LookMaNoImports {
  static Main.F f = s -> // transform a Stream<Boolean>
    s.map(               // by applying its map method
      b ->               // which in turns transforms a boolean 
        !b               // by applying its negation.
    );
}
```

**Main.java**

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class Main {

        interface F {
            Stream<Boolean> f(Stream<Boolean> s);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            F f=LookMaNoImports.f;

            test(f, new Boolean[]{true}, new Boolean[]{false});
            test(f, new Boolean[]{false}, new Boolean[]{true});
            test(f, new Boolean[]{true, false}, new Boolean[]{false, true});
            test(f, new Boolean[]{true, true}, new Boolean[]{false, false});
        }

        static void test(F f, Boolean[] param, Boolean[] expected) {
            List<Boolean> result = f.f(Arrays.stream(param)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (result.equals(Arrays.asList(expected))) {
                System.out.printf("%s: OK%n", Arrays.toString(param));
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s: NOT OK, expected %s%n", Arrays.toString(param), Arrays.toString(expected));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html), 64 bits = 8 bytes

```
0001011000000000010111001011111000001000001100101111011010000010
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8pJ/v/fwMDA0MDQ0AAOQDxDKAUVh5JwURATJvP/PwA)

*Note: This is a function and its list format is slightly different from the list format used by default in BLC’s I/O, so the TIO link doesn’t really do anything.*

### Explanation

If you don’t know what lambda calculus is, please read [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) about it, since Wikipedia explains it better than I can.

My function takes a list of [Church booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans) as input. The list encoding that it uses is [the one where a list is encoded as its right fold function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Represent_the_list_using_right_fold). i.e. The encoding of `list` is `foldr list` (in pseudo-Haskell). An example of this kind of list is `\c n. c (T (c F n))`, where `T` and `F` are the Church booleans for true and false, respectively. This example represents the list `[true, false]`.

Here is the lambda calculus (pseudo-?)code that I used to get my BLC code:

```
\l. l (\a b. \c n. c (a (\x y. y) (\x y. x)) (b c n)) (\c n. n)
```

(`\` is abstraction, `\a b. ...` means `\a. \b. ...`, abstraction extends as far as it can, and application is left-associative.)

I then represented it using [De Bruijin indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index):

```
\1 (\\\\2 (4 (\\1) (\\2)) (321)) (\\1)
```

Note that `321` means `((3)2)1`, not literally a De Bruijin index using the number 321.

Then I used `@` to represent application (i.e. `@mn` means `m(n)`).

```
\@@1\\\\@@2@@4\\1\\2@@321\\1
```

<sub>(Note that I transcribed this “by hand,” so if my answer doesn’t work, then it’s probably a problem with this.)</sub>

I then used this to get the BLC code. (See [here](https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html) for information about how the encoding works and more information about BLC.)

### The actual explanation is here

So I’m going to explain using a condensed version of the lambda calculus notation.

Note that my vocabulary, specifically “the accumulator’ and “the new element”, is probably wrong. I’m basically trying to paint the image of a for loop initializing the “accumulator” at a value and changing it each time it passes through a “new element” of the list.

```
\l.l(\abcn.c(a(\xy.y)(\xy.x))(bcn))(\cn.n)

\l.l(                             )(     )  Right fold of l.
                                    \cn.n   Start the accumulator as the empty list.
     \a                                     a is the new element.
       b                                    b is the accumulator.
        cn.c(                               Prepend...
             a(\xy.y)(\xy.x)                  the logical negation of a
                            )(bcn)            to the accumulator.
```

(This is a high-level overview and it’s probably possible to explain some of these concepts a better way.)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 4 bytes

```
{:!}
```

Input is a list of `0`s and `1`s.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=WzAgMSAxXQoKezohfQoKfnA&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 3 bytes

```
¡!X
```

Japt doesn't have boolean input, so input is an array of 0s and 1s. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=oSFY&input=WzEgMCAwIDEgMCAxXQ==)

#### How it works

```
¡    // Map each item X in the input to
 !X  //  the boolean NOT of X.
     // Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 3 bytes

```
%`0
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JWAw&input=MQoxCjAKMQow)

For each line (`%`), count the number of `0`s.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 24 bytes (non-competing)

```
lambda a:[i-1for i in a]
```

Logic is similar to Steven's, but I tried to use [this](/q/93310#comment227301_93310) comment's idea, but different, because it still takes `0`/`1` arrays, not `0`/`-1`. There is no byte shaving for using `0`/`-1`, so let's be sane. Note that this is non-competing, until Steven or Lynn allows me to use the idea. If so, I *might* remove the non-competing mark. Note that this code cannot be shamelessly stolen, it's still here. Only Steven can use it for his answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 14 bytes

Anonymous function:

```rb
->a{a.map &:!}
```

Test it:

```rb
->a{a.map &:!}.call([true, true, false, true, false, true, true])
# => [false, false, true, false, true, false, false]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia (1 Byte - Thanks to Dennis [See Comments])

```
!
```

Map the logical not to all elements of collection y, works due to automatic vectorization (as Dennis explained). My previous answer was basically using `f(n)=map(!,n)' to map the logical not, but Julia does this on it's own. Jeez, what a cool language. Second time using it, still trying to learn here!

[Try it here](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=Zih5KT1tYXAoISx5KQpwcmludGxuKGYoW3RydWUsZmFsc2VdKSk&input=&debug=on)

Comment: `!` (1 byte) is enough. `!` vectorizes automatically.

Comment: In the console I had it didnt let me do that :(, plus thats a snippet, is it not?

Comment: I've tested it with version 0.4; it's possible that it doesn't work in older versions of Julia. `!` by itself evaluates to a function, which can be saved in a variable (just like a lambda), and is therefore considered a valid function submission. For.example, you can use it like [`f=!;print(f([true,false]))`](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=Zj0hCnByaW50KGYoW3RydWUsZmFsc2VdKSk&input=).

Comment: That's neat, technically 3 bytes for f=! though, unless just saying "!" is its own function works.

Comment: By [community consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9028/12012), `!` is a valid answer on ois own.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6, 9 bytes

```
*.map: !*
```

Usage:

```
say (*.map: !*)((0, 1, 1)) # (True False False)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 2 bytes

```
♂Y
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pmCWQ&input=WzEsMCwwLDFd)

Map (`♂`) Boolean negate (`Y`)

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 12 bytes

```
#(map not %)
```

Basically the same as the Haskell answer. Unfortunately, Clojure doesn't have implicit partial application; thus the function macro.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 byte

```apl
~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24S6/4/6pgLpNAVDBQMgBpEg2uA/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 4 bytes

```
vnot
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeWChIqVigoSi0pqSwoyswrUbDmqlYoAcI0KFn7vywvv@S/3n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
!M
```

Explanation:  (M)ap boolean not (!) over input.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21M&input=%5BTrue%2C+False%2C+True%2C+False%5D&debug=0)

Comment: `m!` works aswell and makes more sense to me since you map the not over the input array.

Comment: @KarlKastor They compile down to the same thing, `assign("Q", eval_input()); imp_print(Pmap(lambda d: Pnot(d), Q))`

Answer (score 1):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 24 bytes

```
|*
*
(turn +< |=(? !+<))
```

Creates a generic gate, map over the contents of the list, negate all loobeans in it.

This uses the normal Hoon tricks, namely using a generic ("wet"/`|*`) gate to avoid having to specify the sample type, along with having unnamed samples (`*` or `?`) and using tree navigation syntax (`+<`) to fetch them.

```
> a 
~[%.y %.n %.n %.y %.n %.y] 
> =f |* 
  * 
  (turn +< |=(? !+<)) 
> (f a) 
~[%.n %.y %.y %.n %.y %.n]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm/tree/develop), 9 bytes

```
,[48-z:,]
```

Assumes that input from stdin is a string of only `"0"`s and `"1"`s, i.e. bytes containing the value `48` or `49`. Prints the negated values to stdout.

**How it works**:
Read one byte from stdin (`,`), and loop (`[]`) until the end of the input. For each byte, subtract 48 (`48-`) and print `1` if the result is 0 and vice versa  (`z` is the zero-flag, `:` prints the given integer value), then get another byte from stdin (`,`)

Run it like e.g. `$ echo -n 001011 | braingasm invert.bg` and get `110100`

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy (19 Bytes)

```
{x->x.collect{!it}}
```

Simple mapping function in a closure.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 12 bytes

```
(map not x)
```

as in:

```
(map not [true false true])
```

=> (false true false)

Updating due to the objection that this is not a function or program:

```
#(map not %)
```

Returns a function that `not`s anything passed to it.

Comment: This isn't a function or program, and preassumes x exists.

Comment: How is that different from the other examples?

Comment: Because the other answers are (mostly) all functions, and don't assume the existence of a variable for their code to work. Your second example is fine though.

Answer (score 1):

### Stata, 20 bytes

```
recode x (0=1) (1=0)
```

x is the input, and the rest is self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 27 bytes

```
def f(a:Boolean*)=a map(!_)
```

Takes a bool array as varargs and maps each element to its inverse.

Comment: The type annotation isn't required is it? Shouldn't it be able to infer the type from `!`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sadly, Scala can't infer the types of method arguments.

Comment: Damn. Forgot about that. That's 9 bytes right there!

Comment: @Carcigenicate I can't use `Int*`, because that's neither truthy nor falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 13 bytes

```
{it.map{!it}}
```

This is a lambda of `(List<Boolean>)->List<Boolean>` type (or `(BooleanArray)->List<Boolean>`, as `map` function on arrays returns lists instead of arrays).

`{it.map{!it}.toBooleanArray()}` would return the result as an actual array.

Answer (score 1):

## sed 8

```
y,01,10,
```

Takes input as 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

`def f(a:Array[Boolean])=a.map(!_)`

Discovered I could remove the second space.
Discovered I could remove brackets.

Answer (score 1):

## Gogh, 4 bytes

```
{!}m
```

Usage:

```
$ ./gogh -noa '{!}m' "1 0 1 0 0 0 1"
[0 1 0 1 1 1 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 15 bytes

```rkt
(curry map not)
```

Basically the Haskell answer.

Comment: Making this a lambda might make this more succinct, no? I was going to partially apply for my answer (`partial map not`,  Clojure), but a function macro ended up being smaller. Idk what Rackets anonymous functions look like though honestly.

Comment: Unfortunately Racket's shortest anonymous function uses the form of `(λ (arguments) function-body)`, so it would be `(λ(l)(map not l))` which is 18 bytes (the lambda symbol is two bytes). Interestingly, `(map not(read))` is also 15 bytes.

Comment: It actually uses a lambda symbol? Damn. That seems needlessly complicated :/

Comment: (There is also `lambda`, but that's not applicable to code golfing at all.)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 2 bytes

```
m!
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=m%21&input=%5B0%2C1%2C1%5D)

```
map(not, input)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Golang, 40 bytes

```
func(a[]bool){for i,b:=range a{a[i]=!b}}
```

#### usage

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    a:=[]bool{true, true, false}
    func(a []bool){for i,b:=range a{a[i]=!b}}(a)
    fmt.Print(a) // => [false false true]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, <s>72</s> <s>69</s> 61 bytes

```
,>++++++++[<------>-]<>+<[->-<]>[<+>-]<>++++++++[<++++++>-]<.
```

Closest i managed to get as BF dosent have Array support

Formatting is stupid, i will fix it when i get a pc... Somehow it wont let me post it as a snippet

Comment: You could put all the lines together into one long line, it doesn't really matter for us (because with newlines, the total byte length is 78 bytes).

Comment: -4: `,>++++++++[<------>-]+<[->-<]>[<+>-]++++++++[<++++++>-]<.`

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, 24 bytes

```
,[>++[->++[<]>-]>-.>>>,]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs-KytbLT4rK1s8XT4tXT4tLj4-Pixd&input=MDEwMDEx)

The same as my [answer to a similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94021/15858).

Relies on 8-bit wrapping cells, the cell size might not matter (untested) but wrapping definitely is. The main part the program is the `>++[->++[<]>-]>-` does some rather convoluted things to flip the last bit of the number.

A shorter solution of 19 bytes is

```
,[+[<[-->>]<--]<.,]
```

but this requires the `<` to noop if the data index is 0, instead of the more typical implementation of going into negative indeces.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 30 bytes

```
foreach($argv[1] as$i)echo!$i;
```

Testing code:

```
$argv[1] = [true,true,false,true,false,false,true,false];
foreach($argv[1] as$i)echo!$i;
```

[Test online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5fe3a13083fac964a1d7c5be04adc6ea1493dd26)

Answer (score 1):

## C++11, 30 bytes

As unnamed lambda:

```c++
[](auto&v){for(auto&x:v)x=!x;}
```

Accepts any standard container like `vector<int>` (but not `vector<bool>`) or `int[]` or `bool[]`.

Comment: For the suggested edit: making this a function would require a return type

Answer (score 1):

## 6502 Machine Language - 14 Bytes

```
AE 00 01 CA B5 00 49 01 95 00 8A D0 F6 00
```

Array of bytes is in zero page. Length of array is in $0100.

Flipped array is in zero page.

Assembler code:

```
AE 00 01 - ldx $0100
CA       - dex
B5 00    - lda $00, X
49 01    - eor #$01
95 00    - sta $00, X
8A       - txa
D0 F6    - BNE (-10)
00       - BRK
```

(My first golf answer - sorry if format is off.)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer! Your formatting is fine, don't worry :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `a`, <s>2</s> 1 byte

*-1 thanks to lyxal*

```
†
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=a&code=%E2%80%A0&inputs=0%0A1%0A0%0A1%0A0&header=&footer=)

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=a&code=%E2%80%A0&inputs=0%0A1%0A0%0A1%0A0&header=&footer=) for 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda s:[~x+2 for x in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaHYKrquQttIIS2/SKFCITNPoTj2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 12 bytes

Input is a string of `a`s for truthy and `b`s for falsy.
These can be replaced with any two distinct characters, as a "proper" falsy value in Lexury *would* be an empty string, however since empty string is empty string, and infinite number of empty strings can be anywhere within a string, so two distinct characters are required.

```
a:
a=>b
b=>a
```

If you want numbers (16 bytes):

```
a:
\1=>\0
\0=>\1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 15 bytes

```arturo
$=>[map&=>not?]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?1tUgP4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```
~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWC-uWFCclF0N5C1ZGG-goGAJRLEQAAA)

Built-in for vectorised logical NOT.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
^1
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=XjE&input=WzEgMCAwIDEgMCAxXQotUQ)

Answer (score 1):

### C, 37 bytes

```
f(a,l)int *a;{for(;l--;*a++=*a?0:1);}
```

a being the array (pointer) and l being the length of the array.

**Readable version**

```
f(t,i)int *t;{ // K&R to save bytes
  for(;i--; // Run i times
  *t++=*t?0:1); // Flip the value of array element and increment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP , 45 Bytes

```
<?foreach($_GET[a]as$v)$a[]=1-$v;print_r($a);
```

Comment: As the question states 'Invert every element of the array and output it.' and people aren't usually too picky on output format, save 6 bytes by doing `print_r($a);` at the end

Comment: Okay I'll try it

Comment: You don't need the spaces there. Your whole code can be written as `<?foreach($_GET[a]as$v)$a[]=1-$v;print_r($a);`. This saves 2 bytes and works.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 51 bytes

```
l.stream().map(b->!b).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

l = a Collection of Booleans
I feel like this could be shorter, then again golfing in java ^^

Comment: Unless the challenge says otherwise, [all submissions need to be full programs or callable functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422), as opposed to snippets which expect the input to be stored in a hardcoded variable. The shortest fix would probably be to wrap what you've got in a simple function body (or lambda, depending on Java version).

Comment: As alternative, you can use streams directly: `s->s.map(b->!b)`. I'm currently [asking on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/are-transformed-versions-of-javas-types-acceptable-as-function-input) if this is acceptable or not.

Comment: Hmmm... Also, you don't reference the packages, either in import or full text.

Comment: If `s->s.map(b->!b)` that @OlivierGrégoire already posted wasn't allowed, you could still golf it by returning an Object-array `l->l.stream().map(b->!b).toArray()` instead (also, as stated by others, your current solution isn't valid. It should have a leading `l->`; `Collectors` should be `java.util.stream.Collectors`; and you can drop the trailing `;`).

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, 7

```
bit-not
```

Negate bits on a bit array.

### Example

```
(bit-not #*00101010010100101001010010101)
=> #*11010101101011010110101101010
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 30 bytes

```
gets.split(?,).map{|e|!eval e}
```

`"true,false"` outputs `false,true`.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Sorry didn't know about that. Newbie here

Answer (score 0):

## Swift(2.2) 44 bytes

I am using x as the input variable here. For example,

```
let x = [true,false]
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

#### Golfed

```
let y = {let b = $0.map({!$0});print(b);}(x)
```

#### unGolfed

```
let y = {
   let b = $0.map({!$0})
   print(b);
}(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (231 Bytes)

```
function flip_bool_array($array) {
  $newarray = array();
  foreach ($array as $bool) {

   if ($bool === true) {
    $bool = false;
   } else {
    $bool = true;
   }

  $newarray[] = $bool;

}

return $newarray;

}
```

### Explanation

The function accepts an array and loops over it testing each value for a true value and setting it to false, if the value is not true then it is set to true. Each boolean is added to a new array and returned.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You could take a ton of bytes off if you remove the extra whitespace, and shorten your variable names down to one letter each. Since the goal is just short code, readability is not important. Also, there's a great thread [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) for tips on golfing PHP code down further.

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 44 bytes

Append this to a line of space-delimited input and echo it into `dc`. Output is delimited with newlines and punctuated with error messages (due to the blatant abuse of `k`). If you quote the stuff, it'll give you even more errors. (When we re-vamp `dc` in the next version, we should probably do something about that.) I suggest pairing with a `2>nul` or other system-specific hack for suppressing whiny programs.

```
0sz[1r-SAlz1+szz0<a]dsax[lzd1-szLApk0<a]dsax
```

Explained:

```
              # "ToS" := "top of stack"
0sz           # Initialise register `z' with 0: this will hold the length of our input
[             # Open macro definition
 1r-          #  Replace ToS with !(ToS): 1-1==0, 1-0==1
 SA           #  Store this result on the top of stack `A'
 lz1+sz       #  Increment z, our length counter
 z0<a         #  If the stack depth is positive, repeat (we still have input to negate)
]dsax         # Store a copy of macro in register `a' and execute it
              # At this point, our input has been negated and stored in A,
              #  first-in-first-out orientation
[             # Open macro definition
 lzd1-sz      #  Decrement z and keep a copy of it for later
 LA           #  Push ToS(A) onto stack; pop from A
 p            #  Peek at ToS
 k            #  `k' is for KILL THE TOP OF STACK BWAHAHAHA
 0<a          #  The value from register `z' is now on top: if positive, we still have
              #   values to print, so repeat macro
]dsax         # I'm in a chaotic mood, so let's just re-use `a'
```

Comment: If you prefer space-delimited output: `s/pk/n32P/`

Answer (score 0):

### dc, 47 bytes

```dc
?zsN0sI[z:az0<A]dsAx[lI1+ddsI;a1r-n32PlN>R]dsRx
```

The actual code to invert a boolean (0 or 1) is `1r-`. The rest is for reading the list and printing it in the same order, which is quite hard because of the (LIFO) stack that dc uses to store the input.

**Explanation:**

```dc
?zsN0sI         # read input, LIFO, initialize N = nr_elements and I = 0 (iterator)
[z:az0<A]dsAx   # loop A: move the stack content into array 'a' (I add a[n] first,
                #then a[n-1], ..., then a[1] and a[0] is not used)
[lI1+ddsI;a     # loop R: increment iterator and push a[I] to stack (input order)
   1r-n32P         #invert value and print it with a space separator
lN>R]dsRx       #repeat (R)
```

**Run:**

```sh
dc -f invert_boolean.dc <<< "1 0 1 1"
```

**Output:** there is a trailing separator (space) at the end, but I hope that's ok

```sh
0 1 0 0
```

**Note:** my answer is similar in concept to that of @Joe's, but there are differences in terms of I/O handling, stack manipulation (I use arrays) and lack of warnings. Do check [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93606/59010) as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Emacs Lisp, 25 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(mapcar'not x))
```

Not very creative.

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 11 bytes

```
(map not l)
```

Testing:

```
(define l '(#t #f #t)) ; define a list of booleans

(map not l)
```

Output:

```
'(#f #t #f)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><> Fish](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) - 9 (16?) Bytes

My second golf and my first in ><> Fish!

```
l?!;r0=nr
```

I'm not sure how to count bytes when flags are considered, but this solution works when running the python interpreter with the -v flag and then space-separated 1's and 0's. If this doesn't match spec, I can remove the answer.

### Example

Input/Run:

```
python fish.py --code "l?!;r0=nr" -v 0 1 0 1 1
```

Output:

```
10100
```

If I'm not allowed to use flags, and instead need to take the input from the input stack (such as on https://fishlanguage.com/playground), the code becomes longer as I must read from the input stack (either 1 or 0 without any separation) until there are no more values, and then convert the char value of the input (1 becomes 49 and 0 becomes 48) to their decimal values before my comparison. I'm not sure how to count bytes for ><> but I believe this would be **16 bytes**.

```
i:1+?!;f3*3+-0=n
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dimwit](https://github.com/MCMastery/dimwit) 8 bytes (non-competing)

```
R1,0}0,1
```

Replaces all 0's with 1's, and vice versa.

Takes input through a string of 0's and 1's, and outputs similarly.
Hopefully that's acceptable ;)

#### [Try it here!](http://dgrissom.com/dimwit/?R1,0%7D0,1)

Comment: Yes, it is :) ...#

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 25 bytes

```
DEF l l
ARYOP 1,l,1,l
END
```

#### Explanation:

```
DEF 'create a function
    l 'named "L"
      l 'with 0 outputs and 1 input named "L"
ARYOP 'array operation
      1 'mode 1 (subtract)
       ,l 'set each element in L to...
         ,1 '1 minus...
           ,l 'the corresponding element in L
END 'end function definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## FALSE, 13 bytes

```
[49^$0>][-.]#
```

Input is a list of `0` and `1` characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 31 bytes

```
proc N L {lmap b $L {expr !$b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFPwUehOic3sUAhSUEFyEytKChSUFRJqq39X5xaApI0UDBQMARig1qugtKSYoVoP6DC2P//AQ)

Comment: It renders more bytes as a command line argument: 
https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6JzexQCFJoVqrViWxKL1MoTq1oqBIQVElqTb2////BgoGCoZAbAAA

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh, 14 bytes

Assumes input is given as arguments. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SKHK2sbGRiVasSr2fy1XmoIBFmiIBeJS9x8A)

```bash
for z;<<<$[!z]
```

Or without bending the rules so much, this uses array I/0 ([26B](https://tio.run/##qyrO@O9oq2GggAkNsUAc6jT/p@UXKVQpaKg4ajpp22qoRCtWxWpy2djYqDj95/oPAA)):

```bash
for z ($A)B+=($[!z])
<<<$B
```

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 24 bytes (6 instrs)

```
00000000: 25010101 82ff0001 73ffff01 a2ff0001  %¢¢¢²”¡¢s””¢ɱ”¡¢
00000010: 5901fffc f8000000                    Y¢”‘ẏ¡¡¡
```

Requires at least one element. Pass array as first argument, length as second.

```
invarr  SUB  $1,$1,1        // loop: i--
        LDBU $255,$0,$1
        ZSZ  $255,$255,1
        STBU $255,$0,$1     // a[i] = !a[i]
        PBNN $1,invarr      // if(i >= 0) goto loop
        POP  0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, <s>43</s> 38 bytes

`n(Z)->lists:map(fun(X)->not X end,Z).`

Many thanks to @Redwolf Programs for saving 5 bytes.

Comment: I don't know Erlang, but can any of that whitespace be removed?